# Minimum bit length needed for a positive integer in Python

Tags: python, bit, bitcount

```
1 = 0b1 -> 1
5 = 0b101 -> 3
10 = 0b1010 -> 4
100 = 0b1100100 -> 7
1000 = 0b1111101000 -> 10
…
```

How can I get the bit length of an integer, i.e. the number of bits that are necessary to represent a positive integer in Python?

Answer (score 208):

In python 2.7+ there is a [`int.bit_length()`](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/stdtypes.html#int.bit_length) method:

```
>>> a = 100
>>> a.bit_length()
7
```

Comment: Curiously, you can't call `bit_length()` on an integer literal.

Comment: @EricWalker Sure you can. You can call a method on any object that has it. There's no exception for literals. You do need to use correct syntax: if you write `2.`, it's a floating point literal, not an integer literal followed by the field access operator. Put a space `2 .bit_length()` or use parentheses `(2).bit_length()`.

Comment: @Gilles'SO-stopbeingevil' thank you for the helpful clarification.

Comment: You can use bit_length() method in python 3 too !

Answer (score 23):

```
>>> len(bin(1000))-2
10
>>> len(bin(100))-2
7
>>> len(bin(10))-2
4
```

**Note**: will not work for negative numbers, may be need to substract 3 instead of 2

Comment: This will not work with negative numbers though (while it also won't fail on it, opposed to the log-versions)

Comment: If you care about negative numbers, do `len(bin(abs(n)))-2`

Comment: More importantly, this fails for `0`.

Comment: Another way is to do `len("{:b}".format(x))` to avoid having to do the subtraction.

Comment: According to the Python Documentation, `bin(n).lstrip('-0b')` works fine for negative numbers, which is equivalent to `bit_length`.

Answer (score 8):

If your Python version has it (≥2.7 for Python 2, ≥3.1 for Python 3), use the [`bit_length`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#int.bit_length) method from the standard library.

Otherwise, `len(bin(n))-2` [as suggested by YOU](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2654149/how-to-count-bits-for-a-number-in-python/2654199#2654199) is fast (because it's implemented in Python). Note that this returns 1 for 0.

Otherwise, a simple method is to repeatedly divide by 2 (which is a straightforward bit shift), and count how long it takes to reach 0.

```
def bit_length(n): # return the bit size of a non-negative integer
    bits = 0
    while n >> bits: bits += 1
    return bits
```

It is significantly faster (at least for large numbers — a quick benchmarks says more than 10 times faster for 1000 digits) to shift by whole words at a time, then go back and work on the bits of the last word.

```
def bit_length(n): # return the bit size of a non-negative integer
    if n == 0: return 0
    bits = -32
    m = 0
    while n:
        m = n
        n >>= 32; bits += 32
    while m: m >>= 1; bits += 1
    return bits
```

In my quick benchmark, `len(bin(n))` came out significantly faster than even the word-sized chunk version. Although `bin(n)` builds a string that's discarded immediately, it comes out on top due to having an inner loop that's compiled to machine code. (`math.log` is even faster, but that's not important since it's wrong.)

Comment: @JonathanEunice Which implementation are you talking about, and why do you think it is incorrect? The bit length of 5 is 3.

Comment: My mistake! I misread the question (as "number of set bits in N" rather than "number of bits to represent N"). I withdraw the criticism.

Comment: I thought the same :P, it's good to know about bit_length though

Comment: For those seeing the above comments, the term for the number of raised bits in a number is called the **population count**, oftentimes abbreviated the **popcount**. This solution is _not_ how to find the popcount - see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/407587/python-set-bits-count-popcount) for how to do popcount in Python.

Answer (score 3):

Here we can also use slicing.

For positive integers, we'd start from 2:

```
len(bin(1)[2:])
len(bin(5)[2:])
len(bin(10)[2:])
len(bin(100)[2:])
len(bin(1000)[2:])
```

which would print:

```
1
3
4
7
10
```

For negative integers, we'd start from 3:

```
len(bin(-1)[3:])
len(bin(-5)[3:])
len(bin(-10)[3:])
len(bin(-100)[3:])
len(bin(-1000)[3:])
```

which would print:

```
1
3
4
7
10
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def bitcounter(n):
    return math.floor(math.log(n,2)) + 1
```

**EDIT** fixed so that it works with 1

Comment: This is off by one for powers of two.

Comment: @Ants Aasma:  Are you sure about that?  It looks fine to me, assuming that math.log(n, 2) gives a perfectly correct result.

Comment: @Ants Aasma: it seems you think that 65536 needs 16 bits. Can you please point us to your PhD thesis? I mean, you have gold in your hands :)

Comment: @MarkDickinson: `math.log(n, 2)` does not give a perfectly correct result.  `math.log(2**29, 2)` = 29.000000000000004, for instance.

Comment: @endolith:  Yep;  I'm scratching my head trying to figure out what on earth I was thinking when I wrote that comment.  FWIW, there's `math.log2` for Python 3, which *does* give exact results for floats that are exact powers of 2.

Comment: @endolith: Though interestingly, on my machine, I get `log(2**n, 2) >= n` for all non-negative `n`, so that `math.floor(math.log(n, 2)) + 1` still gives the correct result for powers of 2.  Though not, of course, for all `n`;  `n = 2**48 - 1` seems to be the smallest value for which it fails.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way:

```
def number_of_bits(n):
    return len('{:b}'.format(n))
```

Not so efficient I suppose, but doesn't show up in any of the previous answers...

Answer (score -2):

This solution takes advantage of `.bit_length()` if available, and falls back to `len(hex(a))` for older versions of Python. It has the advantage over `bin` that it creates a smaller temporary string, so it uses less memory.

Please note that it returns 1 for 0, but that's easy to change.

```
_HEX_BIT_COUNT_MAP = {
    '0': 0, '1': 1, '2': 2, '3': 2, '4': 3, '5': 3, '6': 3, '7': 3}

def bit_count(a):
  """Returns the number of bits needed to represent abs(a). Returns 1 for 0."""
  if not isinstance(a, (int, long)):
    raise TypeError
  if not a:
    return 1
  # Example: hex(-0xabc) == '-0xabc'. 'L' is appended for longs.
  s = hex(a)
  d = len(s)
  if s[-1] == 'L':
    d -= 1
  if s[0] == '-':
    d -= 4
    c = s[3]
  else:
    d -= 3
    c = s[2]
  return _HEX_BIT_COUNT_MAP.get(c, 4) + (d << 2)


# Use int.bit_length and long.bit_length introduced in Python 2.7 and 3.x.
if getattr(0, 'bit_length', None):
  __doc = bit_count.__doc__
  def bit_count(a):
    return a.bit_length() or 1
  bit_count.__doc__ = __doc

assert bit_count(0) == 1
assert bit_count(1) == 1
assert bit_count(2) == 2
assert bit_count(3) == 2
assert bit_count(63) == 6
assert bit_count(64) == 7
assert bit_count(75) == 7
assert bit_count(2047) == 11
assert bit_count(2048) == 12
assert bit_count(-4007) == 12
assert bit_count(4095) == 12
assert bit_count(4096) == 13
assert bit_count(1 << 1203) == 1204
assert bit_count(-(1 << 1203)) == 1204
assert bit_count(1 << 1204) == 1205
assert bit_count(1 << 1205) == 1206
assert bit_count(1 << 1206) == 1207
```

Comment: instead of checking if it has bit_length, you should just try to use it and then `except AttributeError`?

Comment: @endolith: Would it be a significant improvement of this code? In what way?

Comment: well it's more efficient if you're expecting bit_length to be available

Comment: @endolith: Are you sure it's more efficient? (Have you benchmarked it?) Is the difference significant in this case?

Comment: @pts Handling `AttributeError` is considered more Pythonic. e.g., http://stackoverflow.com/a/12265860/687467