# Python check if column exists in list

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm a beginner programmer writing a Python script which ultimately needs to pull the contents of three columns and write them to a new text file. When testing the script, i keep getting the error: `IndexError: list index out of range` applying to the third column I need to pull.

My code:

```
for ip in open("list.txt"):
    with open(ip.strip()+".txt", "a") as ip_file:
        for line in open("data.txt"):
            new_line = line.split(" ")
            if "blocked" in new_line:
                if "src="+ip.strip() in new_line:
                    ip_file.write(", " + new_line[11])
                    ip_file.write(", " + new_line[12])
                    ip_file.write(", " + new_line[14] + "\n")
```

In a few of the lines in `data.txt`, there is no 15th column. I have tried a couple ways to avoid the error message, but I still get the error:

```
if "src="+ip.strip() in new_line:
    ip_file.write(", " + new_line[11])
    ip_file.write(", " + new_line[12])
    if new_line[14] is None:
        pass
    else:
        ip_file.write(", " + new_line[14] + "\n")
```

and

```
if "src="+ip.strip() in new_line:
    ip_file.write(", " + new_line[11])
    ip_file.write(", " + new_line[12])
    if not new_line[14]:
        pass
    else:
        ip_file.write(", " + new_line[14] + "\n")
```

Question: Is there another way to check if the column exists and ignore if does not?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `try-except`:

```
ip_file.write(", " + new_line[12])
try:
    ip_file.write(", " + new_line[14] + "\n")
except IndexError:
    pass
```

By doing `if new_line[14] is None`  or `if not new_line[14]` you're trying to check the value that exists at 14th index, but in python if there's no such index then `IndexError` is raised.

<sub>(In languages like javascript `undefined` is returned for non-existent indexes but that's not the case with python)</sub>

Comment: It's a common practice in Python, to simply try something instead of checking first, if it is possible/existing (EAFP style ("it's Easier to Ask for Forgiveness than Permission"))

Answer (score 0):

The error is caused by the lookup itself (`new_line[14]`), so you have to check the length of the row like `if len(new_line) > 12`. The other approach is handling the `IndexError` exception -- both are good, and usually the programmer can decide which approach to use. See ["Ask forgiveness not permission" - explain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12265451/ask-forgiveness-not-permission-explain)

Answer (score 0):

Using `try` will avoid your exception.

```
try:
    ip_file.write(", " + new_line[11])
except IndexError:
    pass   
try:
    ip_file.write(", " + new_line[12])
except IndexError:
    pass
try:
    ip_file.write(", " + new_line[14])
except IndexError:
    ip_file.write("\n")
```

You were getting an index out of bounds exception when you were doing your comparison to see if it existed.

*NOTE:*
This is probably not what you want to do since each column is likely unique and contains specific information.  If column 2 is missing, this code will not behave as you expect.  We would need to know what is in the columns to help you with that.