# Python OSError while attempting os.mkdir

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
import os
directory=input("Directory: ")
if not os.path.exists(directory):
    os.mkdir(directory)
    os.mkdir(str(directory)+'\steamCMD')
    os.mkdir(str(directory)+'\temporary')
```

A snippet from my code. Returns OSError on the last line shown here. Why? Does exactly same thing as 5th line yet 5th line works like a charm.
Error:

```
    os.mkdir(str(directory)+'\temporary')
OSError: [WinError 123] The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax     is incorrect: 'c:\\testing\temporary'
```

Similar: [Python - os.rename() - OSError: [WinError 123]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21115580/python-os-rename-oserror-winerror-123)
[os.mkdir(path) returns OSError when directory does not exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18973418/os-mkdirpath-returns-oserror-when-directory-does-not-exist)
However he had different mistake to me. Anyone tell me why this is happen?

Comment: It is better to use forward slashes for a [Windows path in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2953834/) anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
os.mkdir(str(directory) + '\\temporary')
```

Or

```
os.mkdir(str(directory) + r'\temporary')
```

About the two `\\` or `r'\temporary'`, [here](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-literals) is the documentation and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19095796/how-to-print-backslash-with-python) is a good question.

---

Also, [`os.path.join()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.join) is a good choice because which uses `\\` on Windows but `/` on *nix. For example:

```
os.mkdir(os.path.join(directory), 'temporary')
```

This gives `directory\temporary` on Windows and `directory/temporary` on *nix. It is a more clear and simple way.

Comment: Also, it's a good idea to use `os.path.join` to build the path, rather than just adding a literal backslash (Windows) or slash (Unix/Linux): `os.mkdir(os.path.join(directory), 'temporary')`.  (It's still good to remember raw strings since you will want them with the `re` module, for instance.)