# How to check if the lines in a csv connection are strings or numbers

Tags: python, string, csv, casting, io

I have a CSV file, `/home/user/file.csv`, such as:

```
V1
1.24
4.55
3
```

I am trying to read in only the numbers, *without the prior knowledge that there is a header*.

How do I read this and skip all `String` elements keeping only ints/floats/long/etc?

The following attempt does not work because `line` is not a number even if the row I am reading is a number:

```
f_in = open('/home/user/file.csv')
for line in f_in:
    if !isinstance(line,basestring):
        #Now we only have the rows that are numbers (but not really!)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
try:
    float(line)
except ValueError:
    # not a number
```

also see ["Ask forgiveness not permission" - explain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12265451/ask-forgiveness-not-permission-explain)

EDIT: as per OP request, a row that looks like:

> 1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,1

```
import csv
with open('/home/user/file.csv') as csvfile:
    for row in csv.reader(csvfile):
        for n in row:
            try:
                float(line)
            except ValueError:
                # not a number
```

Comment: What about  the case of int?

Comment: For a row that is `1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,1`, it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

```
f_in = [1.24, 4.55, 3, "aaa"]

for line in f_in:
    try:
        float(line)
        #it is number
    except ValueError:
        #it isn't a number
```

Answer (score 1):

The `csv` module provides a [`Sniffer`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.Sniffer) class that will figure out if your file has a (one-line) header.

> `has_header(sample)`
>
> Analyze the sample text (presumed to be in CSV format) and return `True` if the first row appears to be a series of column headers.