# Pickle - Load variable if exists or create and save it

Tags: python, serialization, pickle

Is there a better way to load a variable with `pickle` if it already exists or create it and dump it if it doesn't?

```
if os.path.isfile("var.pickle"):
    foo = pickle.load( open( "var.pickle", "rb" ) )
else:
    foo = 3
    pickle.dump( foo, open( "var.pickle", "wb" ) )
```

Answer (score 43, accepted):

You can follow the [`EAFP` principle](https://docs.python.org/2/glossary.html#term-eafp) and [ask for forgiveness](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12265451/ask-forgiveness-not-permission-explain):

```
import pickle

try:
    foo = pickle.load(open("var.pickle", "rb"))
except (OSError, IOError) as e:
    foo = 3
    pickle.dump(foo, open("var.pickle", "wb"))
```

Comment: `IOError` is redundant, writing just `OSError` catches all the same exceptions.

Answer (score 9):

I'd put it in a function for reusability, avoid error catching for control flow on the file, as it's less efficient, and I would use context managers to open the file.

```
import os
import pickle

def read_or_new_pickle(path, default):
    if os.path.isfile(path):
        with open(path, "rb") as f:
            try:
                return pickle.load(f)
            except Exception: # so many things could go wrong, can't be more specific.
                pass 
    with open(path, "wb") as f:
        pickle.dump(default, f)
    return default
```

usage:

```
foo = read_or_new_pickle(path="var.pickle", default=3)
```

`foo` returns `3`

```
foo = read_or_new_pickle(path="var.pickle", default=4)
```

and `foo` still returns `3`.

Admittedly, the following is rather short and elegant, but too many things could go wrong, and you'd have to catch *everything* (don't believe me? try this: `import io, pickle; pickle.load(io.BytesIO(b"\x00"))` and play with the binary):

```
import pickle

def read_or_new_pickle(path, default):
    try:
        foo = pickle.load(open(path, "rb"))
    except Exception:
        foo = default
        pickle.dump(foo, open(path, "wb"))
    return foo
```

Same usage. But I'm concerned the file might not be closed fast enough to avoid an error on opening it the second time in the event of a empty or malformed file. So use the context manager:

```
import pickle

def read_or_new_pickle(path, default):
    try:
        with open(path, "rb") as f:
            foo = pickle.load(f)
    except Exception:
        foo = default
        with open(path, "wb") as f:
            pickle.dump(foo, f)
    return foo
```