# What is the biggest and the smallest URL accepted by VLC

Tags: vlc

I wonder, among all kinds of protocols supported by VLC, which have the smallest and the largest URLs?

I am in doubt as browsers, each has a different number of characters for URL:

```
Internet Explorer: 2,083 characters
Firefox: 65,536 characters
Safari: 80,000 characters
Opera: 190,000 characters
But it is not only the browsers that use URL's, web servers also manage and each interprets its way:

Apache: 4,000 characters
Microsoft Internet Information Server (IIS): 16,384 characters
Perl :: HTTP Daemon: 8000 characters
```

What are the biggest URLs supported by VLC and which are the smallest URLs supported by VLC, because I have to make a validation on a field.

Comment: Why would you need a length validation on an URL? The chance that the URL is wrong because of a typo is much larger, and you can't validate for that. Looks like wasted effort IMO

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12265451/ask-forgiveness-not-permission-explain

Comment: But it also has the minimum size . But the VLC supports several protocols , making it difficult to make a regular expression to validate any URL in VLC . So I like to know what the smallest URL that can exist , because it blocks a bit inserting erroneous URLs. ATT

Comment: It is good to know that the smaller URL possess between 9 and 10 characters . If we consider , FTP, UDP . Will you help me block the URLs that are added with less than 10 characters. Relative to the maximum quantity is not as important as already mentioned above. ATT

Comment: VLC, @Jerry, not VCL. This isn't a Delphi question at all.

Comment: @Rob Oooooooohhhh I missed that tiny detail. Thank you.