# Safely check whether an element in a multidimensional array is undefined in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array, undefined

I want to find out whether an element in some multidimensional array `x` is undefined, for example:

```
typeof x[i][j][k] === 'undefined'
```

The problem is that if for example `x[i][j]` is undefined I get an error. To be on the safe side I would have to instead check:

```
typeof x === 'undefined' 
|| typeof x[i] === 'undefined'
|| typeof x[i][j] === 'undefined'
|| typeof x[i][j][k] === 'undefined'
```

But is there an easier way in JavaScript to check whether `x[i][j][k]` is undefined?

Comment: Are i, j and k integers? Or Strings?  Aren't you using a for loop which provides valid indexes/property names?  Also why does the data have parts that are undefined?  Are not all arrays the same length or are there gaps?

Comment: The dimensions have different length. I am not looping through the whole array. I just need to check some element.

Comment: Could you post a example of your array

Comment: Is your data structure mapped positionally, meaning a certain position in the matrix has a particular meaning ie (x[5][6][3] is x velocity) so you have to refer to specific indexes?  What requires you to have to refer to specific indexes?

Comment: Have you tried !!x[i][j][k]

Comment: @Nitin Just did. But throws an error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can extract this into a [tail-call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/310974/what-is-tail-call-optimization) recursive function that will check arbitrary levels of nesting:

```js
const arr = [1, 2, ['a', 'b', [3, undefined]]];
const OUT_OF_BOUNDS = null;

function getNestedElement(arr, levels, levelIndex = 0) {
  const level = levels[levelIndex];
  if (level < 0 || level >= arr.length) {
    return OUT_OF_BOUNDS;
  }
  return (levelIndex === levels.length - 1)
    ? arr[level]
    : getNestedElement(arr[level], levels, levelIndex + 1);
}

function isNestedElementUndefined(arr, levels) {
  return typeof getNestedElement(arr, levels) === 'undefined';
}

// arr[2][2][0] === 3 which is not undefined
console.log(`arr[2][2][0] = ${getNestedElement(arr, [2,2,0])}`);
console.log(`is it undefined? ${isNestedElementUndefined(arr, [2,2,0])}`);

// arr[2][2][1] is undefined
console.log(`arr[2][2][1] = ${getNestedElement(arr, [2,2,1])}`);
console.log(`is it undefined? ${isNestedElementUndefined(arr, [2,2,1])}`);

// arr[2][2][2] is out of bounds so it will be null
console.log(`arr[2][2][2] = ${getNestedElement(arr, [2,2,2])}`);
console.log(`is it undefined? ${isNestedElementUndefined(arr, [2,2,2])}`);
```

Here's an iterative version as well:

```js
const arr = [1, 2, ['a', 'b', [3, undefined]]];
const OUT_OF_BOUNDS = null;

function getNestedElement(arr, levels) {
  for (const level of levels) {
    if (level < 0 || level >= arr.length) {
      return OUT_OF_BOUNDS;
    }
    arr = arr[level];
  }
  
  return arr;
}

function isNestedElementUndefined(arr, levels) {
  return typeof getNestedElement(arr, levels) === 'undefined';
}



// arr[2][2][0] === 3 which is not undefined
console.log(`arr[2][2][0] = ${getNestedElement(arr, [2,2,0])}`);
console.log(`is it undefined? ${isNestedElementUndefined(arr, [2,2,0])}`);

// arr[2][2][1] is undefined
console.log(`arr[2][2][1] = ${getNestedElement(arr, [2,2,1])}`);
console.log(`is it undefined? ${isNestedElementUndefined(arr, [2,2,1])}`);

// arr[2][2][2] is out of bounds so it will be null
console.log(`arr[2][2][2] = ${getNestedElement(arr, [2,2,2])}`);
console.log(`is it undefined? ${isNestedElementUndefined(arr, [2,2,2])}`);
```

Note: the solutions above assume that `null` is a special value that won't be present in your arrays so it's used to convey a result is not found. If you cannot guarantee `null` won't be in your arrays, you can throw an error or maybe return an object holding the value and a boolean indicating if the value is found.

Something like:

```js
const arr = [1, 2, ['a', 'b', [3, undefined]]];

function getNestedElement(arr, levels, levelIndex = 0) {
  const level = levels[levelIndex];
  if (level < 0 || level >= arr.length) {
    return { found: false };
  }
  return (levelIndex === levels.length - 1)
    ? { value: arr[level], found: true }
    : getNestedElement(arr[level], levels, levelIndex + 1);
}

function isNestedElementUndefined(arr, levels) {
  const { value, found } = getNestedElement(arr, levels);
  return found ? typeof value === 'undefined' : false;
}

// arr[2][2][0] === 3 which is not undefined
console.log(`arr[2][2][0] = ${getNestedElement(arr, [2,2,0]).value}`);
console.log(`is it undefined? ${isNestedElementUndefined(arr, [2,2,0])}`);

// arr[2][2][1] is undefined
console.log(`arr[2][2][1] = ${getNestedElement(arr, [2,2,1]).value}`);
console.log(`is it undefined? ${isNestedElementUndefined(arr, [2,2,1])}`);

// arr[2][2][2] is out of bounds
const { value, found } = getNestedElement(arr, [2,2,2]);
console.log(`arr[2][2][2] = ${found ? value : 'Not Found'}`);
console.log(`is it undefined? ${isNestedElementUndefined(arr, [2,2,2])}`);
```

And it's iterative cousin:

```js
const arr = [1, 2, ['a', 'b', [3, undefined]]];
const OUT_OF_BOUNDS = null;

function getNestedElement(arr, levels) {
  for (const level of levels) {
    if (level < 0 || level >= arr.length) {
      return { found: false };
    }
    arr = arr[level];
  }
  
  return { value: arr, found: true };
}

function isNestedElementUndefined(arr, levels) {
  const { value, found } = getNestedElement(arr, levels);
  return found ? typeof value === 'undefined' : false;
}

// arr[2][2][0] === 3 which is not undefined
console.log(`arr[2][2][0] = ${getNestedElement(arr, [2,2,0]).value}`);
console.log(`is it undefined? ${isNestedElementUndefined(arr, [2,2,0])}`);

// arr[2][2][1] is undefined
console.log(`arr[2][2][1] = ${getNestedElement(arr, [2,2,1]).value}`);
console.log(`is it undefined? ${isNestedElementUndefined(arr, [2,2,1])}`);

// arr[2][2][2] is out of bounds
const { value, found } = getNestedElement(arr, [2,2,2]);
console.log(`arr[2][2][2] = ${found ? value : 'Not Found'}`);
console.log(`is it undefined? ${isNestedElementUndefined(arr, [2,2,2])}`);
```

Comment: This is the awesome way to solve this problem, might be overkill however for this instance. :)

Comment: @GantTheWanderer sure but that depends if the OP needs a general solution or more of a one-time-specific check :)

Comment: I would add `if (arr===null)) {return null;}` inside the for loop to handle the case if `arr[level]` is `null`

Answer (score 2):

`if(x && x[i] && x[i][j] && x[i][j][k]) { }` is one way to do it, based on the premise that `undefined` is a falsy value, and will short-circuit the if-statement if it's encountered.

As an alternative, ["It's easier to ask forgiveness than it is to get permission"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/try...catch). Sometimes you can just try to use it and handle it when it doesn't work using a try-catch block. [Here is another question/answer that explains the philosophy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12265451/ask-forgiveness-not-permission-explain).

Comment: Thanks. But I will still have to walk through all the dimensions. I see however that my formulation of "easier way" is quite vague.

Comment: @Daniel I edited to include an alternate approach. If you're comfortable with kinda smashing through it, you can just use a try-catch block. It's not always recommended, but sometimes it's fine.

Answer (score 1):

There is no other way to put the check except that you can shorten your code by writing it like :

```
if(x && x[i] && x[i][j] && x[i][j][k]) {
 }
```

The above statement goes on checking as long as the term before **&&** keeps returning true.As soon as it finds a false value or **undefined** it shall stop checking the reamining terms.

Answer (score 1):

A nested ternary would be easier, but it's also much less readable.

```
let x = [[[[]]]], // will return true
    i = 0,
    j = 0,
    k = 0;

    let isDefined = x ? x[i] ? x[i][j] ? x[i][j][k] ? true : false : false : false : false;
```

Once any part of the array is removed `isDefined` will return false. It will also evaluate in order, so you could return something else for the false value to notify at what depth it fails.