# fetch the json value if the objects in two jsons match

Tags: python, json

I have 2 json input

json 1:

```
[{
        "Name": "John",
        "Age": "23",
        "Des": "SE"
    },
    {
        "Name": "Rai",
        "Age": "33",
        "Des": "SSE"
    },
    {
        "Name": "James",
        "Age": "42",
        "Des": "SE"
    }
]
```

json 2:

```
[{
        "Name": "John",
        "Age": "23",
        "Des": "SE",
        "tech": [{
            "Primary": ".net",
            "secondary": "java",
            "current": [{
                "first": "Angular",
                "second": "Spring"
            }]
        }]
    },
    {
        "Name": "Ray",
        "Age": "39",
        "Des": "TE"
    }
]
```

when the Name, age and Des parameters match. how to check a particular value for example "Spring" is present in the json 2, if present the desired output is present below

Desired output:

```
[{
    "Name": "John",
    "Age": "23",
    "Des": "SE",
    "tech": [{
        "Primary": ".net",
        "secondary": "java",
        "current": [{
            "first": "Angular",
            "second": "Spring"
        }]
    }]
}]
```

I'm relatively new to python. please help me on this. Thanks

Comment: what is your desired json output?

Comment: @kingkong just edited the question and included the desired output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this code:

```
import json

a = """
[{
        "Name": "John",
        "Age": "23",
        "Des": "SE"
    },
    {
        "Name": "Rai",
        "Age": "33",
        "Des": "SSE"
    },
    {
        "Name": "James",
        "Age": "42",
        "Des": "SE"
    }
]
"""

b = """
[{
        "Name": "John",
        "Age": "23",
        "Des": "SE",
        "tech": [{
            "Primary": ".net",
            "secondary": "java",
            "current": [{
                "first": "Angular",
                "second": "Spring"
            }]
        }]
    },
    {
        "Name": "Ray",
        "Age": "39",
        "Des": "TE"
    }
]
"""

# Covert to list dict python
json_dict1 = json.loads(a)
json_dict2 = json.loads(b)

def has_value(obj, val):
    if isinstance(obj, dict):
        values = obj.values()
    elif isinstance(obj, list):
        values = obj
    if val in values:
        return True
    for v in values:
        if isinstance(v, (dict, list)) and has_value(v, val):
            return True
    return False

elems = set((d['Name'], d['Age'], d['Des']) for d in json_dict1)

for e in json_dict2:
    if (e['Name'], e['Age'], e['Des']) in elems and has_value(e, "Spring"):
        print(e)
```

Reference for check `Spring`: [How to know if a value exists in a list within a nested dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50090011/how-to-know-if-a-value-exists-in-a-list-within-a-nested-dictionary)

Comment: the main point would be to check the presence of Spring in the json 
think we are missing that in the solution

Comment: @Dev I modify as you wish