# Python - check if key exists in a dict with lot of subdictionaries

Tags: python, dictionary

I am trying to return True if a key already exists in the big dictinary or any subdictionary that is a part of this dict and False if it does not:
here is my code:

```
def find_key(key, dicto):
    for k, v in dicto.items():
        if k == key:
            return v
        elif isinstance(v, dict):
            for result in find_key(key, v):
                return result
```

where am I going wrong ? 
   here what i want :

```
data = {
    "spam": {
        "egg": {
            "erwan": "Well..",
            "a": "ezeaea",
            "sausages": "Spam egg sausages and spam",
            "jih": "je sais pas "
        },
        "oui": ''
    }
}
find_key("oui", data) return True
find_key("jih", data) return True  
find_key("oezea", data) return False
```

Comment: No already tried and didn't work i want to return True if it exist and False otherwise

Comment: look here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43491287/elegant-way-to-check-if-a-nested-key-exists-in-a-python-dict

Comment: not the same case, i want to check if a key exist not a list of key in order

Comment: How about you check the list at the end and if it's empty return False, otherwise True.  Just because the duplicate doesn't give you an exact solution does not make it not useful.  You need to put forth some effort.

Comment: yes how that possible, this what i m looking for

Comment: You can use Recursion maybe. I cant comment because this is blocked, but take each element in your original dic, and run the same function on it, and then recursively check the dics in them etc, return true if one returns true.

Comment: Something like this:     def keys_exists(element, key):
     if type(element) is not dict:
        return false
     if dict in element.keys: return true
     rec = Map(lamda x: keys_exists(x), element.values)
     return True in rec