# Python3 Checking if nested dictionary keys are identical

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary

I'm trying to loop over a dictionary with nested keys to see if they're identical or not. If they are not (IE, false) I need to trigger separate logic in my program.

I've pasted an example of the dictionary/JSON where I'm looking to check if the nested key_of_interest are all the same. In this case, they are false (`abc` vs `def`)

```
[{'name': 'set-1',
  'name': [{'name': 'rule-1',
    'outer_key': {'key_of_interest': {'secondary_key': [None]}}},
   {'name': 'rule-2',
    'outer_key': {'key_of_interest': [None]}}]}]
```

I've tried various combinations of `if all` without success... any guidance would be appreciated.

Thanks!
Edit: Reason why 'Elegant way to check if a nested key exists in a python dict' doesn't apply is discussed below

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Elegant way to check if a nested key exists in a python dict](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43491287/elegant-way-to-check-if-a-nested-key-exists-in-a-python-dict)

Comment: Eh, it's less about searching for a specific key to see if it exists (it could be anything...), it's that they're all equal (or not) to each other.

Comment: Are you just worried the keys are the same or the actual values are equal?

Comment: Technically I'm worried if the keys are *not* equal (==). They're strings, not that it should matter. Just need to iterate over all keys (could be 100's) to make sure they're identical. If not, I have to add additional logic

Comment: In the example are you trying to check whether the __values__ under all the keys called `key_of_interest` are the same? (Also what does `abc` vs `def` refer to?)