# Is there an easy way to use a nested dictionary entry and ensure none of the keys are missing?

Tags: python

I want to do the following with less code:

```
if "address" in structured_data:
    if "addressCountry" in structured_data["address"]:
        data["country"] = structured_data["address"]["addressCountry"]
```

Is this possible?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Elegant way to check if a nested key exists in a python dict](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43491287/elegant-way-to-check-if-a-nested-key-exists-in-a-python-dict)

Comment: What do you want to happen when a key is not there?

Comment: Do you want to throw an exception if the key isn't there, silently return None, or create a new element (like `defaultdict` does)? Since you have an if-ladder of guard clauses, seems like silently return None (?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about using a `try`?

```
try:
    data["country"] = structured_data['address']['addressCountry']
except KeyError:
    pass # handle what you want to do
```