# check if json element or object exists or not and proceed

Tags: python

Hi im am trying to parse json data and gets this error every time the element

```
 if ['fields']['assignee'] in each:
 TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
 >>>
```

My json is this

```
{
"expand": "schema,names",
"startAt": 1,
"maxResults": 50,
"total": 7363,
"issues": [
    {
        "expand": "operations,versionedRepresentations,editmeta,changelog,renderedFields",
        "id": "591838",
        "self": "https://jira.mynet.com/rest/api/2/issue/591838",
        "key": "TEST-8564",
        "fields": {
            "summary": "delete  tables 31-03-2020 ",
            "customfield_10006": 2.0,
            "created": "2020-02-27T10:29:12.000+0100",
            "description": "A LOT OF TEXT",
            "assignee": null,
            "labels": [
                "DATA",
                "Refined"
            ],
            "status": {
                "self": "https://jira.mynet.com/rest/api/2/status/10000",
                "description": "",
                "iconUrl": "https://jira.mynet.com/",
                "name": "To Do",
                "id": "10000",
                "statusCategory": {
                    "self": "https://jira.mynet.com/rest/api/2/statuscategory/2",
                    "id": 2,
                    "key": "new",
                    "colorName": "blue-gray",
                    "name": "To Do"
                }
            }
        }
    }
 ]
}
```

The element in ['fields']['assignee'] is NULL in this example 
sometimes it is like this

```
"assignee": : {
                "self": "https://mynet.com/rest/api/2/user?username=xxxxxx",
                "name": "sij",
                "key": "x",
                "emailAddress": xx@mynet.com",
                "avatarUrls": {
                    "48x48": "https://mynet.com/secure/useravatar?ownerId=bdysdh&avatarId=16743",
                    "24x24": "https://mynet.com/secure/useravatar?size=small&ownerId=bdysdh&avatarId=16743",
                    "16x16": "https://mynet.com/secure/useravatar?size=xsmall&ownerId=bdysdh&avatarId=16743",
                    "32x32": "https://mynet.com/secure/useravatar?size=medium&ownerId=bdysdh&avatarId=16743"
                },
                "displayName": "Bruce Springsteen",
                "active": true,
                "timeZone": "Arctic/Longyearbyen"
            },
```

I am trying to check of assignee is null and if so print null

my code looks like this

```
with open('C:\\TEMP\\testdata.json') as json_file:
    data = json.load(json_file)
    for each in data['issues']:
        if ['fields']['assignee'] in each:
            print (['fields']['assignee']['name'])
        else:
            print ('null')
```

I have tried to put in [0] between ['fields']['assignee']['name'] but nothing seems to help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Elegant way to check if a nested key exists in a dict?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43491287/elegant-way-to-check-if-a-nested-key-exists-in-a-dict)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with

```
if 'fields' in each and 'assignee' in each['fields']:
```

Note that you need the name of the key, *not* surrounded by square brackets.

Perhaps better:

```
for each in data['issues']:
    print(each.get('fields', {}).get('assignee', {}).get('name', 'null'))
```

and if you can't guarantee that 'issues' exists in `data` either:

```
for each in data.get('issues', []):
    <as before>
```

`data.get('issues', [])` returns an empty list if `data['issuess']` doesn't exist.

Comment: when trying   try:
            print(str(each['fields']['assignee']['name']))
        except KeyError:
            print('null') i get the error print(str(each['fields']['assignee']['name']))
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
>>>

Comment: @havmaage I've adjusted the code, so it's more failproof. It now always gets a default if a key does not exist, including the 'null' string at the end, so there is no need for a try-except or if-else (that is implicit in the `.get()` method).

Comment: NB: you don't need to convert a value explicitly to `str` inside a `print` function: print does that for you.

Comment: thx, i am now getting this error:  print(each.get('fields', {}).get('assignee', {}).get('name', 'null'))
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get' am i missing an libray class, my imports is only  import json

Comment: @havmaage That means `each` is `None`, which suggests your input data is just too messy.

Comment: got it i did this  if each.get('fields', {}).get('assignee', {}):
          print(each.get('fields', {}).get('assignee', {}).get('displayName', 'null')) Thanks al lot