# How to find the last matched key by comparing with list and dictionary

Tags: python

A list and dictionary is below

```
main_list = ["projecttype","emptype","Designation"]
sample = {"query": {
      "emptype":["Manager"],"projecttype":["temp"],
    "from": [
      "0"
    ],
    "q": [
      ""
    ],
    "size": [
      "4"
    ]
  }}
```

1. How to find from the main_list which key is `last` "entered key" in sample dictionary
2. How to find from the main_list which key is `first` "entered key" in sample dictionary

In this particular scenario

1. `"projecttype"` is my output for last entered key which matches
2. `emptype` is my output for first entered key which matches

Comment: Perhaps this is splitting hairs, but technically `query` is the only key in your `sample` dict. Is there a reason your example needs a dict in a dict, and each of the inner dict's values is also wrapped in a single-value list?

Comment: @CrazyChucky my sample dict is very big i just extract the `query`  from that

Comment: Dictionaries only recently added the ability to order by insertion order.  You'll need to be using a very recent version of Python, and use `dict.items()` with slicing.

Comment: Maybe this could help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43491315/10011503

Comment: To follow up on Mark Ransom's comment, dicts have been de facto ordered since 3.5, and are only *guaranteed* to be ordered since 3.7. If you're using an older version, you could use OrderedDict.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can iterate through it and test if the keys are in your `main_list`. Save every key that is in `main_list` and after the for loop you will have the last entered key.

```
main_list = ["projecttype","emptype","Designation"]
sample = {
    "query": {
        "emptype": ["Manager"],
        "projecttype": ["temp"],
        "from": ["0"],
        "q": [""],
        "size": ["4"]
    }
}

first = None
last = None
for key, value in sample['query'].items():
    if key in main_list:
        if first is None:
            first = key
        last = key
print('First:', first)
print('Last:', last)
```

Comment: instead of `for key, value in sample['query'].items():`, you could simplify that slightly to `for key in sample['query'].keys():`. No sense unpacking the values if you don't use them.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this in a cuple of lines and have the order of all the elements that are contained in your `main_list` as follow:

```
sample_query_keys = list(sample['query'].keys())
result = {sample_query_keys.index(main_key):main_key for main_key in main_list if main_key in sample_query_keys}
```

Then you can get the first and last item as follow:

```
print(result[0], result[len(result)-1])
```

Keep in mind that this will only work if the dictionary is ordered. That is only possible in Python 3.7 onwards. For previous versions, you would need to use OrderedDict.