# Python 3: Testing presence of each (sub)key in nested dict vs just using a try block? Poor practise or OK?

Tags: python

May I ask: is the try block 2nd option considered poor practice? And if so, is there a more succinct way of testing a nested dict before referencing a sub key that may or may not exist?

Coming to python from perl...

Thank you :)

```
b = None
# a['x'] = {}
# a['x']['y'] = Wibble
if 'x' in a and 'y' in a['x']:
  b = a['x']['y']
if b is not None:
  # Do stuff with b
```

vs

```
b = None
try:
  b = a['x']['y']
except:
  pass
if b is not None:
  # Do stuff with b
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Elegant way to check if a nested key exists in a dict?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43491287/elegant-way-to-check-if-a-nested-key-exists-in-a-dict)

Comment: I generally use this way if not very deeply nested https://stackoverflow.com/a/61158507/2308683

Comment: Thanks @fynmnx - I see that try-except is considered "good" there. I'll go with that because it's brief and clean. Useful to see that they only catch the specific exception KeyError


Many thanks for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
> b=a.get("x",{}).get("y")
  if b:
    #Do stuff with b
```

Comment: A very interesting technique - thank you for that :)

Comment: the `.get()` method is a safe way to attempt to grab a key value and return a default if it's not there. The first `get()` checks for key 'x' and returns an empty dict if it's not there. This ensures the next `get()` will be called on a dict. The second `get` will return either the value under 'y' or `None` (the default if a default return is not specified)

Answer (score 0):

I'd go for the new walrus operator in 3.8:

```
a = { 'b': { 'c': 1, 'd': 2 }, 'e': {} }

if (b := a.get('b')) and (c := b.get('c')):
   print(c)
```

so if `b` is not present `a.get('b')` will return None and the `and` condition would return `False`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes its even recommended as a common coding style: [It is easier to ask for forgiveness than permission.](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-EAFP)

The only thing I would change is to not catch all exceptions, but just `KeyError`. And also I would use the `else` case to do the processing, instead of the `None` test.

```py
try:
  b = a['x']['y']
except KeyError:
  pass
else:
  # do stuff with b
```