# For looping returns only 1 and random answers while scraping (python)

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a issue with looping it is a simple code that should return 7 answers, however it just returns 1 answer (also this answer varies between the 7 options)

Can you see any direct flaws?

Thanks for the help.

---

```
import requests
import bs4

my_url = 'http://www.promittere.se/'

res = requests.get(my_url)    

#html parsing
page_soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(res.text, 'html.parser')

#Container
containers = page_soup.findAll("li")

for container in containers:
    title = container.a.text

print("title: " + title)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your identation is off.

I would encurage you to read and follow:  [How to debug small programs (#2)](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) and familiarize yourself with a debugger - they are great tools to fix your errors yourself.

---

Python uses indented block to group things together - mostly for loops / conditions / try catch / file operations:

- `for in in range(10):`
- `if 1==2:`
- `try: ... except:`
- `with open(...) as f:`

or f.e for function/classes/etc.

Your `print()` command is *outside* your loop so it will only ever print the last title that was captured in the `for` loop above it.

**Fix it like this:**

```
for container in containers:
    title = container.a.text

    print("title: " + title)  # this needs to be indented to belong _into_ the loop
```

Be aware that `container` might not contain anything (on other pages) and that the `li`-elements also might not contain a "`a href`" inside (on other pages) - directly accessing `container.a.text` might give you an error if container does not contain any `a` - tag.

Use error handling: [ask-forgiveness-not-permission-explain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12265451/ask-forgiveness-not-permission-explain) to catch errors when they occure to make your code more robust.

See https://docs.python.org/3.6/tutorial/errors.html

Comment: Hi and thank you Patrick. Could you please show me what you mean with My script  above? Not shure I understand. This is more or less my first try at scripting.

Comment: @roa - See my answer: **Fix it like this** - I indented the printing so now it belongs to the "body" of the `for`-loop

Answer (score 0):

thank you so much for your help. It was the indentation fails, its corrected and now it works. 
BR 
R