# Elif statement printing when it shouldn't

Tags: python, python-3.x

This is a part of our assignments for Computer Programming in high school. These are the instructions. https://prospect.schoolloop.com/file/1407107943880/1376109333800/2888156401519472863.pdf

```
def c7():
    myList = [7, 10, 94, 2, 54, 2, 19, 4, 11]
    print (myList)
    valueToSearch = int(input("Enter the value to search for: "))

    for n in range(0, len(myList)):
        if valueToSearch == myList[n]:
            print (myList[n], "is in index", n)
        elif (n == len(myList)-1) and (valueToSearch != myList[n]):
            print ("No matches")
```

For example:

```
>>> c7()
[7, 10, 94, 2, 54, 2, 19, 4, 11]
Enter the value to search for: 1
No matches
>>> c7()
[7, 10, 94, 2, 54, 2, 19, 4, 11]
Enter the value to search for: 7
(7, 'is in index', 0)
No matches
```

The last line "No matches" is unexpected when the input is 7.

Comment: Because you **always** check on each iteration. Regardless of whether or not you've found your value... so regardless of whether you find `19` at index `6`, you still check `elif (n == len(myList)-1) and (valueToSearch != myList[n])`, which happens to be true on the last iteration...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
def c7():
    myList = [7, 10, 94, 2, 54, 2, 19, 4, 11]
    print (myList)
    valueToSearch = int(input("Enter the value to search for: "))

    for n in range(0, len(myList)):
        if valueToSearch == myList[n]:
            print (myList[n], "is in index", n)
        elif (n == len(myList)-1) and (valueToSearch not in myList):
            print ("%s is not found in list"%valueToSearch)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you find the value in the list, you should stop searching.

```
for n in range(0, len(myList)):
    if valueToSearch == myList[n]:
        print (myList[n], "is in index", n)
        break
    elif (n == len(myList)-1) and (valueToSearch != myList[n]):
        print ("No matches")
```

You could then improve this by using python's for-else clause:

```
for n in range(0, len(myList)):
    if valueToSearch == myList[n]:
        print (myList[n], "is in index", n)
        break
else:
    print ("No matches")
```

Comment: But if you break, you'll stop after the first match.

Comment: @TimPietzcker: True. If duplicates are in the list this would only print the first value,

Answer (score 1):

Think about what happens if you enter a number that isn't 11. Let's say you pick `2`.

The final item is reached. At this point, `n == len(myList)-1)` is `True`, and since `2 != myList[n]`, that condition is `True` as well, so "No Matches" is printed.

You could use another variable (e. g. `found = False`) that is set to `True` as soon as the first match is found, and then check for that at the end of the loop.

Answer (score 1):

You iterate over the list, for each value it checks if it is equal to your looked for value, if it is, it prints the one thing, else the other - hence you get one output per element in the list.

Edit: reread and saw you need to find all, not only the first:

```
def c7():
    myList = [7, 10, 94, 2, 54, 2, 19, 4, 11]
    print (myList)
    valueToSearch = int(input("Enter the value to search for: "))

    foundOne = False # none found so far
    for idx,value in enumerate(myList): # enumerate gives you index + value of each elem
        if value == valueToSearch:
            print (valueToSearch, "is in index", idx)    
            foundOne = True  # found (at least) one

    if not foundOne: 
        print ("No matches")
```

---

If you had to only get the first, simply get the [index of the element](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html) in the list and capture the error if it is not in it.

That fits with pythons [ask forgiveness not permission](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12265451/ask-forgiveness-not-permission-explain):

```
def c7findFirst():
    myList = [7, 10, 94, 2, 54, 2, 19, 4, 11]
    print (myList)
    valueToSearch = int(input("Enter the value to search for: "))
    try:
        idx = myList.index(valueToSearch)
        print (valueToSearch, "is in index", idx)
    except ValueError: # capture the error if thing is not in list
        print ("No matches")
```