# Stylize cell if word found in Pandas DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-styles

I've seen online how to format a [Pandas DataFrame with `.style`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.18/style.html).

However, I have a table with a bunch of text, and would like to be able to format the cells, depending on the words inside. Borrowing from this logic in the above linked reference:

```
def color_negative_red(val):
    color = 'red' if val < 0 else 'black'
    return 'color: %s' % color
```

For example, color the cell red if the word "BBC" is in a cell. Color it green if "XYZ" is in the cell.  Color it black if "ZYX" is in the cell, etc.

```
def style_dataframe(val):
    color = "red" if "BBC" in val else "white" # fuzzy match 'BBC'
    color = "green" if val == "XYZ" else color # find exact match
    color = "black" if val == "ZYX" else color # find exact match
    return 'background-color: %s' % color   
...   
df.style.applymap(style_dataframe)
df.to_html("test.html")
```

However, this doesn't color anything.

Screenshot of `test.html`:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You have the general idea, good job!

The part you need to add is actually *rendering* the formatting.

Before saving the `html`, do so like this:

```
...
stylized_df = df.style.applymap(style_dataframe)
with open("test.html","w") as html:
    html.write(stylized_df.render())
```

Note: you can't do `if "bbc" in val` as you get the error

> TypeError: ("argument of type 'NoneType' is not iterable", 'occurred at index author')

To fix that, adjust the `If` statement flow:

```
def style_dataframe(val):
    color = "white"
    if val is not None:
        if "bbc" in val:
            color = "red"
        if val == "The Wall Street Journal":
            color = "green"
    return 'background-color: %s' % color
```

Comment: @AsheKetchum instead of the `if not None`?

Comment: @Batman Yeah, i think there's the idea about "Ask forgiveness not permission". I thought it was in the zen of python but maybe I saw it somewhere else.
Maybe something like https://stackoverflow.com/a/12265860/7571052 ? I guess it doesn't make a huge difference in this case :)