# Write a program that prompts for an integer and prints the int, if anything else is entered ask again till a integer is input

Tags: python

I'm writing a program that prompts for an integer and prints the integer, but if something other than an integer is input, the program keeps asking for an integer.

I can't figure out how to get it to reset properly. I have tried different methods but nothing works.

This is my code so far:

```
inp = input ("Enter a Integer:")
while inp.isdigit():
    print (inp)
    break
else:
    print ("Enter a Integer")
```

Does anyone have some suggestions?

Comment: What isn't working? Do you get an error, unexpected behavior?

Comment: I don't want to give the answer straight away. But think like this. Why not putting the test `isdigit` in an if block inside the loop? If it is correct, you break, else it will go again in the loop.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Asking the user for input until they give a valid response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23294658/asking-the-user-for-input-until-they-give-a-valid-response)

Answer (score 1):

Its better to follow pythons [Ask forgiveness not permission](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12265451/ask-forgiveness-not-permission-explain) stratagem :

```
while True:
    try:
        k = input("integer:")    # gets a string
        k = int(k)               # tries integer conversion
        break                    # if success: break while True loop
    except ValueError:
        print("Try again.")      # int() failed

print(k)                         # print the output
```

Output:

```
integer:a
Try again.
integer:b
Try again.
integer:5
5
```

Advantage: this works even for negative integers, the `isdigit()` check does not.

Exceptionhandling: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html#handling-exceptions