# How to find input index is available in Matrix or not in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, matrix, arraylist

How i can find the index number is available in matrix or not?
Like

import numpy as np

```
R= np.matrix ([1,2,34,4,5,5,6,9], 
              [1,2,34,4,5,5,6,9],
              [1,2,34,4,5,5,6,9])
```

Here i want to search my input index is available or not in "R"

```
Here my input index is C[4,4]
```

I want to find if C[4,4] index is available then he returns True otherwise False
Please help me how i can find.

Comment: as @Pythonista said; in code that would look like 

    def(index, shape): 
        return all([i < j and i > 0 for i, j in zip(index, shape)])

Comment: @ GlobalTraveler can you write the code with my above description?

Comment: It already is ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your matrix definition lacks surrounding `[` .... `]`.

---

You can either use the [Ask for forgiveness not permission](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12265451/ask-forgiveness-not-permission-explain) approach or test if your given indexes do not exceed the shape of the matrix:

```
import numpy as np

R = np.matrix ([             # missing [
    [1,2,34,4,5,5,6,9], 
    [1,2,34,4,5,5,6,9],
    [1,2,34,4,5,5,6,9]
])                           # missing ]

print( R.shape )  # (3,8)



def indexAvailable(M,a,b):
    # ask forgiveness not permission by simply accessing it
    # when testing for if its ok to access this    
    try:
        p = M[a,b]
    except:
        return False
    return True

print(99,22,indexAvailable(R,99,22))
print(9,2,indexAvailable(R,9,2))
print(2,2,indexAvailable(R,2,2))
```

Output:

```
99 22 False
9 2 False
2 2 True
```

Or you can check all your given indexes against the shape of your matrix:

```
def indexOk(M,*kwargs):
    """Test if all arguments of kwargs must be 0 <= value < value in M.shape"""
    try: 
        return len(kwargs) == len(M.shape) and all(
            0 <= x < M.shape[i] for i,x in enumerate(kwargs))
    except:
        return False

print(indexOk(R,1,1))    # ok
print(indexOk(R,1,1,1))  # too many dims
print(indexOk(R,3,7))    # first too high
print(indexOk(R,2,8))    # last too high
print(indexOk(R,2,7))    # ok
```

Output:

```
True
False
False
False
True
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just check the dimensions of the matrix.... `np.matrix.shape`

Comment: @ Pythonista You mean instead of "np.matrix" , i need to add "np.matrix.shape" 

But when i did like this 
R= np.matrix.shape ([1,2,34,4,5,5,6,9], 
              [1,2,34,4,5,5,6,9],
              [1,2,34,4,5,5,6,9])
it is giving an error 
'getset_descriptor ' object is not callable