# Python Function with list as argument OR multiple values as argument

Tags: python, function

I want to write a python function `my_sum` that extends python's built-in `sum` in the following way:

- If a sequence is passed to `my_sum` it behaves like the built-in `sum`.
- If multiple values are passed to `my_sum`, it returns the sum of the values.

**Desired output**:

```
my_sum([1, 2, 3])  # shall return 6 (similiar to built-in sum)
my_sum(1, 2, 3)    # shall return 6 as well, (sum throws TypeError)
```

What worked was the following.

```
def my_sum(*x):
    try:
        return sum(x)  # sums multiple values
    except TypeError:
        return sum(*x)  # sums sequence of values
```

Is that the pythonic way to accomplish the desired behavior? For me the code looks odd.

Comment: this doesn't belong here but in Code Review, I am voting to close this

Comment: What is odd about it? try:..except is fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is pythonic. I think at least one check is required and python has the philosophy "Ask for forgiveness not permission" (explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12265451/ask-forgiveness-not-permission-explain)) which basically means that using try-except blocks is OK for standard control flows.

If importing an established library is pythonic and something you are allowed and willing to do, you can use [numpy.sum](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.1/reference/generated/numpy.sum.html) too, as follows:

```
import numpy as np
def my_sum(*x):
    return np.sum(x)
```

With this definition, both

```
my_sum([1, 2, 3])  
my_sum(1, 2, 3)
```

return `6`.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is not an use case for exceptions, exceptions are for exceptional cases. Use another function if you convert arguments to a list and pass to the adder function.

In addition, the validation and formatting of the input should be in the outer part of the code, not in the final function. In the best case the data should be validated before coming to this function, and you should only have the `sum` function to deal with the cooked data.

It's a way to:

- Keep things simple
- Avoid adding conditional paths
- Avoid defensive programming in inner code
- And thus avoid future problems.

I would have the following code.

```
def argsToList(*x):
  return list(x)  

print sum([1,2,3,4])
print sum(argsToList(1,2,3,4))
# both output 10
```