# How to use dictionary to execute multiple functions?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I have a dictionary `switcher` in this piece of code:

```
def a():
    print("A")

def b():
    print('B')


def switch(mode):
    switcher = {
        'a': a,
        'b': b,
        'ab': (a, b)
    }
    switcher[mode]()

switch('a')
```

If I use `switch('a')` I get the output:

> A

So far using `switch('ab')` returns an error:

```
TypeError: 'tuple' object is not callable.
```

How would I be able to execute both `a` and `b` using `switch('ab')`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By introducing a for loop for the iterable

```
def a():
    print("A")

def b():
    print('B')


def switch(mode):
    switcher = {
        'a': a,
        'b': b,
        'ab': (a, b)
    }
    for i in mode:
        switcher[i]()

switch('ab')
```

**Output**

```
A
B
```

Comment: Note you don't need to (and probably don't want to) define `'ab': (a, b)` in your dictionary. Strings are iterable. Better, but equivalent in this case, is to use `switch(('a', 'b'))`.

Comment: This works assuming the third key is superset of the other two.

Comment: To understand what I mean, what if the keys were "x", "y" and "z"? To make things more complicated, this will only work if the keys are characters!

Comment: for i in mode: switcher[i]()   -> When you use switch('ab') This doesn't actually call 'ab', it's iterating through the string as a sequence and first doing a lookup on 'a' which calls the function a, then doing a lookup on 'b', which calls the function b. The 'ab' key isn't called.  This may not be an issue since it provides the desired behavior of calling function a then function b.

Answer (score 2):

The error here is caused by your dictionary storing two different types of things: the values associated with keys `'a'` and `'b'` are "just" a function, while the value for `'ab'` is a tuple of functions.

Based on the principle of idiomatic Python code [asking forgiveness, not permission](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12265860/1417451), I suggest *trying* to call the element of the dictionary as "just" a function, and if that fails, trying to iterate over each function in the tuple.

```
def switch(mode):
    switcher = {
        'a': a,
        'b': b,
        'ab': (a, b)
    }
    try:
        switcher[mode]()
    except TypeError:  # must be a tuple of functions
        for fn in switcher[mode]:
            fn()
```

Answer (score 1):

You could handle the third case (where it is a tuple of functions) separately:

```
def a():
    print("A")
def b():
    print('B')
def switch(mode):
    switcher = { 'a': a, 'b': b, 'ab': (a, b) }
    if type(switcher[mode]) is tuple:
         for func in switcher[mode]:
            func()
    else:
         switcher[mode]()

switch('ab')
```