# Code is written to support multiple arguments, but fails when only one argument is given. sys.argv[1] + sys.argv[2]

Tags: python, web-scraping, translators

My current code uses a variable "word", so word = sys.argv[1] + sys.argv[2], which works great when I have two arguments, but when I only have one argument then i get IndexError: list index out of range

I am writing a program that Defines words by pulling the info from dictionary .com. I am following very closely a video tutorial because I am just trying to learn how to get a basic dictionary to work, (long term goal being write a translation app that is independent of google translate api or anything like that). I have a code that works in that it pulls the definition when you type in the word, but not when you type in 2 words, examples will be below. SO I added an argument, which worked for 2 words but no longer works for one word.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import sys

url = "https://www.dictionary.com/browse/"

word = sys.argv[1] + sys.argv[2]

url+= word
r = requests.get(url)
soup = bs(r.content, "lxml")


try:
    pos = soup.findAll("span", {"class" : "luna-pos"})[0].text #luna-pos is an html tag
    definitions = soup.findAll("ol")
    meanings = definitions[0].findChildren("li", recursive=False)
    print(word + ": " + pos)
    for (i,meaning) in enumerate(meanings):
        print(str(i + 1), meaning.text)
except:
     print("Word not found")
```

Expected results:
Print word, part of speech, and definition.
I.e Define the word (being a single argument) "Proper"
Also Define "Self Control" (two word argument)

Comment: just check how many args you have before trying to access the non existant [2] index? basic `if` condition.

Comment: @ParitoshSingh Not really the best solution. Then what will happen with 3 arguments? 4? 100?

Comment: aye thats true.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a good use-case for slicing. You want everything after the first argument in the list, so as a slice this translates to `[1:]`. So just use:

```
word = ''.join(sys.argv[1:])
```

For example:

```
>>> args = ['scriptname.py', 'the']
>>> ''.join(args[1:])
'the'
>>> args = ['scriptname.py', 'self', 'control']
>>> ''.join(args[1:])
'selfcontrol'
```

Comment: @JadonMurphy Consider accepting the answer if it solved your problem.

Comment: @bitto I will be it just says I have to wait some minutes. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

**Slicing:**

You can use list slicing to avoid the error:

```
word = ''.join(sys.argv[1:]  # joins 1st to last ..
```

or

```
word = ''.join(sys.argv[1:3]  # 1st and 2nd without error
```

List slicing works even if the slice index is larger then the amount of elements in the list.

---

**Testing:**

The other way to handle it would be to test first then append:

```
if len(sys.argv) == 2:
    word = sys.argv[1]
elif len(sys.argv) >= 3:
    word = sys.argv[1]+sys.argv[2]
else:
    word = "" # no input given
```

---

**Error handling**:

Try it and handle the error if it happens (see *Ask forgiveness not permission* below)

```
try:
    word = sys.argv[1]+sys.argv[2]
except IndexError:
    word = sys.argv[1]
```

Readup:

- [Understanding Python's slice notation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/understanding-pythons-slice-notation)
- [len() check](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#len)
- ["Ask forgiveness not permission" - explain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12265451/ask-forgiveness-not-permission-explain)
- [try: except:](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html#handling-exceptions)