# How to Print a Specific Item in a List if the Input is outside of index

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to have this code return a list item if it's within the index, but if it's not in the index to just default to a specific item in the index

Below code is an example:

```
messages = ["Hello", "Howdy", "Greetings"]
user_num = int(input("Enter a Number Between 1-3: "))
def message_prompt(num):
    num_check = num - 1
    message = messages[num_check]
    if message in messages:
        print(message)
    else:
        print(messages[2])
message_prompt(user_num)
```

With this code it just errors out at message because the variable is outside of the scope of the index. 
What can I do to fix this?

Comment: your own sentence has the hint."return a list item **if** it's within the index, **but**... " Why dont you do an if check to see if the input number would be within the index range for the list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you rather use *ask permission* you can test first:

```
messages = ["Hello", "Howdy", "Greetings"]
user_num = int(input(f"Enter a Number Between 1-{len(messages)}: ")) - 1 # make it zero based

def message_prompt(num):
    print(messages[num if num < len(messages) else -1]) # default to the last one

message_prompt(user_num)
```

although python propagates  ["Ask forgiveness not permission"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12265451/ask-forgiveness-not-permission-explain) (i.e. `try: ... except: ...`)

This `num if num < len(messages) else -1` is a ternary expression that uses `num` if small enough else defaults to -1 (the last element).

See: [Does Python have a ternary conditional operator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/394809/does-python-have-a-ternary-conditional-operator)

Answer (score 2):

Python does not support indexing a list with an invalid index. One idiomatic solution is to use `try` / `except`:

```
messages = ["Hello", "Howdy", "Greetings"]
user_num = int(input("Enter a Number Between 1-3: "))

def message_prompt(num):
    try:
        print(messages[num - 1])
    except IndexError:
        print(messages[2])

message_prompt(user_num)
```

Do note that negative indices are permitted. So the above solution won't error if `-2` is input; in this case, the penultimate list item will be printed.

Answer (score 0):

you can use try except, or validate the value in a while loop until a legal input is specified:

```
messages = ["Hello", "Howdy", "Greetings"]
user_num = int(input("Enter a Number Between 1-3: "))
def message_prompt(num):
num_check = num - 1
    try:
        message = messages[num_check]
        print(message)

    except IndexError:
        print(messages[2])

message_prompt(user_num)
```

i recommend on reading on try except block to protect from user input.