# Filter by either index level or column when I don't know whether my field is an index level or column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a DataFrame with a number of index levels and a number of columns. I have a field that I know is either the name of an index level or the name of a column, but I don't know which. I wish to filter my DataFrame on this field. If the field were an index level, I would do `df[df.index.get_level_values(field) == 0]`, and if it were a column I'd do `df[df[field] == 0]`, but since I don't know which it is I'm stuck. Is there a way to let pandas figure out whether the field name is in the index or the columns and grab the Index/Series as appropriate?

I know that I could reset the index and then set it back, but this seems dumb and potentially problematic if not all of the index levels are named.

Comment: Simple; it fails fast, so wrap in a `try`/`except`

Comment: So catch the `KeyError` when it can't find it in the columns? That seems... ugly

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12265451/ask-forgiveness-not-permission-explain

Comment: Actually, I posted a link that wasn't the one I was thinking of :P It's still probably the easiest way to my mind.

Answer (score 0):

Since you mentioned it's either column or index label, then try:

```
if field in list(df.columns):
   #do df[df[field] == 0]
else:
   #do df[df.index.get_level_values(field) == 0]
```