# Is there a python idiom for determining if set of keys is in a dictionary object (dict)?

Tags: python

I want to check if keys are present in a `dict`.

There are several ways I can think of to do this:

```python
# (1) using 'in'
if 'my_key' in my_dict.keys() and 'my_other_key' in my_dict.keys():
    ...

# (2) using set.subset
if set(('my_key', 'my_other_key')).issubset(set(my_dict.keys()))
    ...

# (3) try-except
try:
    ... # do something with my_dict['a_key'] and my_dict['my_other_key']
except KeyError:
    pass
```

None of these are particularly intuitive to read, especially (2) if more than a few key names need to be tested while still complying with PEP 8 line length of 80.

What I would like is something along the lines of

```python
if my_dict.keys() contains (
        'key1',
        'key2',
        'key3'):
    ...
```

Is there a python idiom similar to the above, or do I need to grumble for a bit and then write a utility function?

Comment: define `('my_key', 'my_other_key')` as a variable and use that is `set.subset` ?

Comment: I prefer not to assign variables if they are only going to be used once. I feel like it interrupts the flow of the code to break a single logical operation info multiple statements.

Comment: well isn't that why we use variables?

Comment: You can do `{'my_key', 'my_other_key'} <= set(my_dict.keys())`. The curly braces represent a `set` and `<=` is the subset operator. I think any answer would be opinion based but many people like to follow [Ask Forgiveness, Not Permission](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12265451/ask-forgiveness-not-permission-explain)

Comment: To follow up on my previous comment, you could do `if set(my_dict.keys()) >= {'key1', 'key2', 'key3'}:` to get something along the lines of what you want, *but* `try/except` is perfectly fine as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are checking that they are all members, if you name your set of necessary keys set_of_keys

```
if all(key in my_dict.keys() for key in set_of_keys)
```

In fact, the way membership checks work for dictionaries, using .keys() is unnecessary. You can just check

```
if all(key in my_dict for key in set_of_keys)
```

Comment: If you dont want to define set_of_keys explicitly, just wrap all the keys you want to check in any iterable

Comment: I did not know `all` was builtin. That actually helps clear up a lot of issues I've had with python's support for fold-like operations.

Comment: Yep! As you may now guess, any is builtin as well.