# IndexOutOfBound and storing with comma split

Tags: python, indexoutofboundsexception

If a string either follow this format such as `'a,b,c,d'` (where `a`,`b`,`c`,`d` are all `int`) or completely empty.
For example:

```
179,170,271,83
null
143,406,299,44
145,403,299,44
142,404,299,44

31,450,337,36

null

90,269,242,32
87,266,244,35
null
272,251,223,119
27,40,316,10
```

How can I store the value of `a`,`b`,`c`,`d`?

I tried using the split comma and check for empty string, but it doesn't help

```
if string:
      txt = string.split(',')
      height = txt[0]
      left = txt[1]
      top = txt[2]
      width = txt[3]
else:
      height = ""
      left = ""
      top = ""
      width = ""
```

Comment: How are you reading your input? Can you post examples for a non-empty string and an empty string from your input?

Comment: Do you really have empty lines and also lines containing the string `null`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the length of `txt`:

```
if string:
    txt = string.split(',')
    if len(txt) == 4:
        height = txt[0]
        left = txt[1]
        top = txt[2]
        width = txt[3]
    else:
        height = ""
        left = ""
        top = ""
        width = ""
else:
    height = ""
    left = ""
    top = ""
    width = ""
```

Comment: Thank you so much, it worked fine! I guess I didn't check the length.

Answer (score 2):

It's common in Python to use `try`/`except` in cases like this rather than testing first. This is often referred to as [asking for forgiveness not permission](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12265451/ask-forgiveness-not-permission-explain). To do this you could wrap the expected case in the `try` and set edge case in the except:

```
def printDims(s):
    try:
        height, left, top, width = s.split(',')
    except ValueError:
         height, left, top, width = [''] * 4
    finally:
        print(height, left, top, width)


printDims("1,2,3,4") # prints 1, 2, 3, 4
printDims("")        # prints the empty strings
```

Comment: I will look into it. ty :)