# Catch AttributeError only on a specific attribute

Tags: python

Is there a way to catch `AttributeError` on a specific attribute only ?

e.g. I want this code to pass if `foo` doesn't have a `bar` attribute but `AttributeError` exception to be thrown if it doesn't have `baz` an attribute.

```
try:
   a = foo.bar + foo.baz
except AttributeError:
    pass
```

I could write

```
if hasattr(foo, 'bar'):
    a = foo.bar + foo.baz
```

But I'd [rather ask forgiveness than permission](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12265451/ask-forgiveness-not-permission-explain)...

Comment: `foo.bar = ...` will create the attribute `bar` if it doesn't already exist. The only error you can get is if `foo` somehow disallows attributes to be created after initialization.

Comment: In other words, this already does exactly what you are asking it to do.

Comment: Your alternative implies you don't want an `AttributeError` for a non-existing `bar` attribute, but some other error if `bar` *already* exists.

Comment: How about raising an error for the inverse: `if not(hasattr(foo, 'bar')): raise AttributeError`?

Comment: @chepner Ok, my example is bad. Let me please edit it so it makes more sense.

Comment: @usr2564301 Using a condition before executing the code is *asking for permission*...

Comment: If you have control over `type(foo)`, you could override `__getattr__` to raise a different exception (though still a subclass of `AttributeError`) for `bar`, and only catch that exception, rather than all `AttributeError`s.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, like all the coding zen statements, the forgiveness vs permission principle is not an absolute one. In this case in particular you know for sure that the first that will happen inside the `try/except` block is the raise of the `AttributeError`, but you might find yourself in situations where the `AttributeError` is raised after additional operations that are costly or have side effects.

```
def some_function(foo):
    costly_operation()
    insert_something_to_a_database(foo)
    return foo.bar + foo.baz

try:
    some_function(foo)
except AttributeError:
    # All the work done was not needed and it may even have
    # left traces (like the db insert) that now need to be undone.
```

In these cases, it is simpler, safer more readable and more efficient to check for permission before executing anything rather than performing unneeded operations or even trying to fix the mess afterwards.

If, anyways, you really need to ask for forgiveness rather than permission you can simply check for permission afterwards: You go ahead assuming that everything is right and, if there is an error, you figure out if it was the one that you want to raise or not.

```
try:
   some_function(foo)
except AttributeError:
    if not hasattr(foo, 'bar'):
        raise
```

Answer (score 1):

Move the attribute access whose exception you *don't* want to catch out of the `try` block.

```
x = foo.baz
try:
    a = foo.bar + x
except AttributeError:
    pass
```