# Finding element index in nested list

Tags: python, list

Looking to find the element index of an element in a nested loop.

```
table = [
    [1, "Y", 3],
    [4, 5, "K"]
]      
for i in range(len(table[0])):
    for j in range(len(table)):
        print(table[i].index("Y"))`
```

But every time I run the the code it tells me Y is not in my list

Comment: `for t in table:
    if "Y" in t:
        print(t.index("Y"))`

Answer (score 3):

You don't need the nested loop. You can loop through the rows and call `index()` on the row. You can catch the error that will happen when `Y` is not in the list. This is a Python style of asking [forgiveness instead of permission](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12265451/ask-forgiveness-not-permission-explain):

```
for row in table:
    try:
        print(row.index("Y"))
    except ValueError:
        pass
```

If you just want to know if 'Y' is in the table you can use `any()`:

```
any('Y' in row for row in table)
# True
```

Comment: Sorry about that I didn't specify that I was looking for the column index!

Comment: @SadTacoMadTaco `row.index("Y")` will give you the column index.

Answer (score 1):

Your inner loop doesn't make any sense; `index` already covers the entire list; why do you need to do that 3 times?

You will get an error if the item doesn't appear.  Instead

```
for i in range(len(table)):
    if 'Y' in table[i]:
        print(i, table[i].index('Y'))
```

For each row, you check whether `Y` appears.  If it does, then you print the row and column number where it appears.

Comment: `index["Y"]` is invalid.

Comment: @Prune, I suggest you also add the first iteration in your answer for clarity