# using try, except with Maya Python to check to make sure items in a selection are the correct node type

Tags: python, maya

**I am struggling with how to know when to use try/except verses if/else when checking the node types of selected nodes, and how to use try/except in a situation like below.

**I want to do something like this:****

```
selected_nodes = cmds.ls(sl = True)

for selected_node in selected_nodes:

    #example one

    validate_node_type = validate_nodes(selected_node)
        if validate_node_type == True
            return True
        else:
            return False

    def validate_nods(selected_node):
        node_type = cmds.node_type(selected_node)
        if node_type == 'file':
            return True
        else:
            return False
    
    #example two, or is better to use try/except?

    try:
        validate_nodes(selected_node)
        return True
    except:
        return False
    
    def validate_nodes(selected_node):
        selected_node_type = nodeType(selected_node)
        try:
            selected_node_type == 'file'
            return True
        except:
            return False
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In short, you would use `if/else` to perform a logical check, and `try/except` to wrap code that might throw an **error** and prevent the rest of your code from executing.

In your specific example, `node_type = cmds.nodeType(selected_node)` *might* throw an error, so if you're going to use try/except anywhere, this is probably the place.

Sometimes though, throwing an error is completely the right thing to do -- especially if the operation is not unattended.

Personally, I would refactor your code to look like this:

```py
def validate_fileNodes(nodes):
    '''Check if a single or list of objects are of type `file`
    
    Args:
        nodes (str|list [str]): Nodes to check

    Returns:
        bool: True if all matches, False otherwise
    '''

    if not isinstance(nodes, (list, tuple)):
        nodes = [nodes]
    
    for node in nodes:
        if cmds.nodeType(node) != 'file':
            return False

    return True

selected_nodes = cmds.ls(sl=True)
valid_files = validate_fileNodes(selected_nodes)

print('Selected nodes are valid files? {}'.format(valid_files))
```

Keeping in mind that this *may* throw an error if you feed it bad info, but how you handle that should probably be dealt with outside of your validation function.

**Edit:** In answer to comments, to catch errors I would do it here:

```py
selected_nodes = cmds.ls(sl=True)
valid_files = None

try:
    # This method may raise an error, but we catch it here instead of in the method itself
    valid_files = validate_fileNodes(selected_nodes)
except Exception as e:
    print('validate_fileNodes method raised an exception: {}'.format(e))

if valid_files == True:
    print('Selected nodes are valid!')
elif valid_files == False:
    print('Selected nodes are not valid, but the check went well')
else:
    print('The check failed. We dont know whats going on here')
```

Comment: Thank you, I would I use try,except with the nodeType command? My mind keeps going to if, else... Because try does not have a condition check in its line. Also, what exception error would it be throwing if it is not a file node?

Comment: The nodeType command will only throw errors (like most Maya functions) if you feed it incorrect or unsolvable node names. I haven't actually tested this, but that's how most of the `cmds` commands work. In reality though, if you're grabbing a user's selection you are pretty safe for this type of command. I have updated my answer to address your question a bit more thoroughly

Answer (score -1):

You might be over complicating this. If all you want to do is check to see if a list of nodes are a file type then it could be done in almost a one-liner:

```
import maya.cmds as cmds

def is_node_type(objs, node_type="file"):
    return len(cmds.ls(objs, type=node_type)) > 0

is_node_type(cmds.ls(sl=True))  # Check with current selection.
```

You can pass a list of objects to `cmds.ls` and specify the parameter `type` to whatever you want to check. Returning the length of that directly will return `True` if that type exists in the collection of objects, or `False` if it doesn't. Since the function also has `node_type` parameter you can easily change it to something else without hard-coding it.

At that point you can do whatever you want with it. Generally you can stick with `if` `else` conditions. Though some cases might be long winded when you nest many `if` statements, so in that case you can predict errors that might arise and catch it with `try` `except`. I believe this is like [EAFP (Easier to ask for forgiveness than permission)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12265451/ask-forgiveness-not-permission-explain). There are some cases where you have no choice but to use `try`, and this is usually when external factors are involved, like relying on your internet connection or connecting to some server that may be down.

Comment: Not sure, but my take on this question is that OP is obviously new to programming, or at least Python. So emphasis on readability seems more valuable than one-liners and otherwise optimised-but-hard-to-read code.