# How can I fix this 'NoneType' AttributeError?

Tags: python, web-scraping, attributeerror, nonetype

I am busy doing a tutorial in python, and I am busy doing some Web Scraping. When the instructor runs the program he does not get any errors, however, when I run the program I receive an attribute error. The tutorial was made late last year, so the format of the website has changed a bit. however, I have managed to work around that.
I am web scraping forecast.weather.gov
The weird thing is that I ran a similar line before that and it worked perfectly, so I am really confused!
Here is the code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

page = requests.get('https://forecast.weather.gov/MapClick.php?lat=34.05349000000007&lon=-118.24531999999999#.X8qd1NgzZPY')
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
week = soup.find(id="seven-day-forecast-body")
# print(week)

items = week.find_all(class_='forecast-tombstone')
#print(items)

print(items[1].find(class_='period-name').get_text())
print(items[1].find(class_='short-desc').get_text())
print(items[1].find(class_='temp').get_text())

period_names = [item.find(class_='period-name').get_text() for item in items]
short_descriptions = [item.find(class_='short-desc').get_text() for item in items]
temperature = [item.find(class_='temp').get_text() for item in items]
print(period_names)
print(short_descriptions)
print(temperature)
```

And this is the output:

```
Overnight
Partly Cloudy
Low: 49 °F
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Bongi/PycharmProjects/Qazicourse/Web Scraping.py", line 18, in <module>
    temperature = [item.find(class_='temp').get_text() for item in items]
  File "C:/Users/Bongi/PycharmProjects/Qazicourse/Web Scraping.py", line 18, in <listcomp>
    temperature = [item.find(class_='temp').get_text() for item in items]
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get_text'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Notice how there is only an error with this line,

```
temperature = [item.find(class_='temp').get_text() for item in items]
```

and not this one,`print(items[1].find(class_='temp').get_text())`

I am a complete beginner with coding(not just python), so I am very sorry if I made this too long. Any suggestions would be much appreciated!

Comment: Your code works fine for me. Maybe you have been requesting too often and weather.gov uses some kind of scraping protection, resulting in a different response.

Comment: The reason you get this is that `item.find(class_='temp')` is `None`. Either handle errors with `try: ... except: ...`  or check if it is `None` before accesing it. See [ask-forgiveness-not-permission-explain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12265451/ask-forgiveness-not-permission-explain)

Comment: Hi, the code works fine now :). It was just the layout of the website, the changed it  2-3 days after I posted this.