# Finding a file that matches pattern in a directory using Python and emailing if not found

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to find if a given file pattern is available in a directory. If found, I would want to open and load as JSON. If not found, I would like to send an email saying that the file is not present.

**File name: test_09082021.txt**

```
import os

path ='/dev/stage/'
file_pattern = 'test*'

file = path + file_pattern

if os.path.isfile(file):
   with open(file) as f:
      data = json.load(f)
else:
   mailserver.sendmail('abc@gmail.com','def@gmail.com',msg.as_string())
```

But the application couldn't find the file and is returning false in the IF statement.

Could you please advise how I can check for the file pattern to make this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use `glob` library:

```py
import glob
import json

path ='/dev/stage/'
file_pattern = 'test*'

pattern = path + file_pattern
matched_files = glob.glob(pathname=pattern)
try:
   with open(matched_files[0]) as f:
      data = json.load(f)
except IndexError:
    mailserver.sendmail('abc@gmail.com','def@gmail.com',msg.as_string())
```

Use `try`, `except` block, according to python [ask forgiveness not permission](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12265451/ask-forgiveness-not-permission-explain) principle.

`glob()` returns list of files, which matched the desired pattern. If there is no file, python will throw `IndexError` and you send email. Otherwise first file is opened as json.

Comment: Thank you ! This solution worked for me :)

Answer (score 1):

Your code doesn't work because it checks if a file with the given name "test*" exist - that's not the same as creating a list of all files that have a pattern.

Have a look at the following for an example of using file patterns:
[Find all files in a directory with extension .txt in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3964681/find-all-files-in-a-directory-with-extension-txt-in-python)