# Python While loop: list index out of range, but still can get the answer

Tags: python

I am a beginner of python, I tried to test the while loop.
For below code, I can get the answer, but still get the out of range error.
I know the available seat is much larger than the name list,
and all people can get a seat.
The result showed the answer that I want.
But it shows out of range.
How can fix the out of range problem?
Thanks

```
name_list=["Peter", "John", "Gary", "Amy"]
available_seat=10
entered_people=0
while available_seat > entered_people:
    element=name_list[entered_people]
    print(element +" can enter.")
    entered_people+=1
print("Next time please.")
```

Peter can enter.
John can enter.
Gary can enter.
Amy can enter.
IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: `name_list[entered_people]` is valid only if `entered_people` is a value from 0 to 3. You get `IndexError` when it is outside of this range.

Comment: you know there are `for` loops that are specifically meant to be used to iterate over iterables such as lists

Comment: @Matiiss yes, I know the for loops, but just want to try if using while loop can solve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you still want to use a while loop, you can go about it this way. Make an iterator to go through the elements in name_list. If you are able to reach the last element then your iterator should be equal to the length of name_list. "Next time please" won't be printed in that case. See the code below:

```
name_list=["Peter", "John", "Gary", "Amy"]
available_seat= 10

length = len(name_list)
i = 0 # Variable to iterate through name_list

while available_seat and (i < length):
    print(name_list[i] + " can enter.")
    i += 1
    available_seat -= 1
    
# Only print "Next time please" if you did not reach last person in name_list
if i != length:
    print("Next time please")
```

Comment: Thanks, it works! I can make the comparison then.

Answer (score 0):

You should iterate over the list of names rather than using this while loop. That way you won't try to access an index that doesn't exist in the `name_list` array. You can also get rid of the `entered_people` variable and only use `available_seats` and decrement it by 1 everytime someone enters. Here is a much cleaner solution.

#### Code

```
name_list=["Peter", "John", "Gary", "Amy"]
available_seats = 10

for name in name_list:
    if available_seat > 0:
        print(name +" can enter.")
        available_seats -= 1
    else:
        print(name +" can't enter.")
```

#### Output

```
Peter can enter.
John can enter.
Gary can enter.
Amy can enter.
```

Comment: there is also `enumerate` so that you don't need to do this subtraction

Comment: @DollarAkshay Thanks, I use for loop at first. But want to try if while loop can solve it. Thanks for your reply!

Comment: @GaryCL. Definitely use this for loop syntax. Its more "pythonic" and cleaner looking code. Please do not forget to select an answer as accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

You get `IndexError` because you are trying to use an index beyond the size of the list. One way to fix the problem is to check this in the `while` condition:

```
while available_seat > entered_people and entered_people < len(name_list):
```

Comment: Thanks, it can fix the index error. But it print the answer "Next time please." also. I try to figure it out. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @GaryCL. Please post a new question. Be sure to explain what you are trying to accomplish with this program.

Answer (score 0):

I hope following may help. len is used identify len of the name list.

```
name_list=["Peter", "John", "Gary", "Amy", "gg", "xx", "yy", "dd", "kk", "mm"]

available_seat=10 
entered_people=0

while available_seat >= entered_people:
    if entered_people == available_seat:
        print("Next time please.")
        break
    elif entered_people < len(name_list) and entered_people != available_seat:
        element=name_list[entered_people]
        print(element +" can enter.")
        entered_people+=1
        #print(entered_people)
    elif len(name_list) < available_seat:
        print(f"We have still {available_seat - len(name_list)} seat available.")
        break
```

sample outputs:

Peter can enter.
John can enter.
Gary can enter.
Amy can enter.
baris can enter.
xx can enter.
yy can enter.
dd can enter.
kk can enter.
We have still 1 seat available.

```
Peter can enter.
John can enter.
Gary can enter.
Amy can enter.
We have still 6 seat available.
```

Answer (score -2):

Catch the `IndexError` and break the loop:

```
while available_seat > entered_people:
    try:
        element=name_list[entered_people]
    except IndexError:
        print("All people seated!")
        break

    print(element +" can enter.")
    entered_people+=1
```

Comment: A better solution would be to avoid the `IndexError` in the first place.

Comment: If you want the exception to end the loop, put the try/except around the loop instead of inside it. Then you won't need the break.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice, not necessarily: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12265451/ask-forgiveness-not-permission-explain. Asking forgiveness is at least as good as asking for permission.

Comment: @khelwood, however, I'd like to be sure that the exception occurred _on this specific line_, not elsewhere in the loop. If OP adds other code to the body of the loop, that code could produce an unrelated `IndexError` that I don't want to catch. I'm catching this specific exception because I know exactly why it happened - because all people have been given a seat. Catching it here also lets me report it correctly.

Comment: I mean, if you know the exact reason in this likely single-threaded environment, then you might as well _ask for permission_, which would seemingly reduce the amount of code needed too, depending on implementation. It is as though intentionally letting an exception happen when you could prevent it seems "wrong" in a way. It is a solution nonetheless so I don't know why this was downoted