# Delete certain keys from a nested dictionary using dictionary comprehension

Tags: python, dictionary, dictionary-comprehension

I have to work with a nested dictionary filled with numbers in python 'my_dict', and a list that specifies the subkeys 'keys 'that have to be deleted:

```
keys=[1,9]
my_dict={1:{1:a, 2:b}, 2:{1:c, 3:d, 9:e}}
```

I want to have two outcomes:
Delete all subkeys+their values if they are in keys, e.g.

```
new_dict={1:{2:b}, 2:{3:d}}
```

Or Delete all subkeys+their values if they are not in keys, e.g.

```
new_dict:{1:{1:a}, 2:{1:c,9:e}}
```

I have tried:

```
new_list = {outer_k: {inner_k: inner_v for inner_k, inner_v in outer_v.items()-{1,9}} for    outer_k,  outer_v in my_dict.items()}
```

It gives me back the same dict without deletion of the elements, same for the second szenario

```
new_list = {outer_k: {inner_k: inner_v for inner_k, inner_v in outer_v.items()&{1,9}} for    outer_k,  outer_v in my_dict.items()}
```

I have also tried:

```
for key, value in my_dict.items():
    for key1, value1 in value.items():
        for key1 in keys:
            try:
                 del dict[key1]
            except KeyError:
                 pass
```

This gives me the error:

`TypeError: 'type' object does not support item deletion`

I would be glad if anyone knows of a neat solution for this!

Comment: `del dict[key1]`   vs   `del my_dict[key1]`   - `dict` is the build in .... whereas `my_dict` is your instance of your dict.

Comment: oh wow, I completely missed that.. thanks!

Comment: @PatrickArtner is right. And BTW looks like `for key1 in keys:` should be an `if` statement.

Comment: Your "code" did also never run ... else you would have seen that you got lots of NameErrors in `my_dict={1:{1:a, 2:b}, 2:{1:c, 3:d, 9:e}}`

Answer (score 0):

Using dict comprehension:

```
new_dict = {k_out : {k_in : v_in for k_in, v_in in v_out.items() if k_in in keys} for k_out,v_out in my_dict.items()}
```

Comment: Thanks! That was exactly what I was looking for and it works perfectly fine now :)

Answer (score 0):

The error `TypeError: 'type' object does not support item deletion` stems from

> ```
> for key, value in my_dict.items():
>     for key1, value1 in value.items():
>         for key1 in keys:
>             try:
>                  del dict[key1]    # this is the build in, not your instance
>                                    # fix:    del my_dict[key1]
>             except KeyError:
>                  pass
> ```

As for the comprehensions - they look rather long ....

```
keys = [1,9]
my_dict = {1:{1:"a", 2:"b"}, 2:{1:"c", 3:"d", 9:"e"}}


# delete top levels 
# for unwanted_key in keys:
#     try:
#         del my_dict[unwanted_key]
#     except KeyError:
#         pass

# delete inside sub levels 
for unwanted_key in keys:
    for inner_key in my_dict:
        try:
            del my_dict[inner_key][unwanted_key]
        except KeyError:
            pass

print( my_dict)
```

Results in

```
# {2: {3: 'd'}}               # if you do top level and sub level

{1: {2: 'b'}, 2: {3: 'd'}}   # if you only do sub levels
```

The `try: ... except: ...` follows ["Ask forgiveness not permission" - explain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12265451/ask-forgiveness-not-permission-explain)

Answer (score 0):

For your example , i recreated the data to runnable,
however deleting directly from the dict you' re iterating on will throw an error , you can do it by creating a copy of a dictionary where will your result will be stored

```
keys=[1,9]
my_dict={1:{1:"a", 2:"b"}, 2:{1:"c", 3:"d", 9:"e"}}
my_dict

new_dict1=my_dict.copy()
for key, value in my_dict.items():
    if key1 in value.keys() and key1 in keys:
          # delete subkeys and their sub values
          del new_dict1[key][key1]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can modify *my_dict* *in situ* like this:

```
keys = [1, 9]
my_dict = {1: {1: 'a', 2: 'b'}, 2: {1: 'c', 3: 'd', 9: 'e'}}
for v in my_dict.values():
    for k in keys:
        if k in v:
            del v[k]
print(my_dict)
```

**Output:**

```
{1: {2: 'b'}, 2: {3: 'd'}}
```