# Python Dictionary Throwing KeyError for adding list of tuples

Tags: python, dictionary

Here is original text file:

```
s1 10 s2
s2 12 s3
s3 25 s1
s1 14 s3
```

I am making a dictionary of first value in each line as a key, the output should be:
{'s1': [**('s2', 's10'), ('s3', '14')**], 's2': [('s3', '12')], 's3': [('s1', '25')]}

When i run my code I get a key error:

```
def graph_dict(filename):
    dictx = {}
    with open(filename) as x:
        for i in x:
            c, c1, c2 = i.split()
            dictx[c] += [(c2,c1)]
        return dictx

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#361>", line 1, in <module>
    graph_dict("filename.txt")
  File "*********************************************", line 7, in graph_dict
    dictx[c] += [(c2,c1)]
KeyError: 's1'
```

in the above line when I  make it into dictx[c] = [(c2,c1)] I get output;

```
{'s1': [('s3', '14')], 's2': [('s3', '12')], 's3': [('s1', '25')]}
```

And so it is throwing a key error as attempting to add a list of 2 tuples to "s1", which I thought should be okay.  Does anyone have advice to get output:

```
{'s1': [('s2', 's10'), ('s3', '14')], 's2': [('s3', '12')], 's3': [('s1', '25')]}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`dictx[c] += [(c2,c1)]` assumes that `c` already exists in the dictionary. You could test instead. And use .append to be a little faster.

```
def graph_dict(filename):
    dictx = {}
    with open(filename) as x:
        for i in x:
            c, c1, c2 = i.split()
            if c in dictx:
                dictx[c].append((c2,c1))
            else:
                dictx[c] = [(c2, c1)]
        return dictx
```

Comment: perfect, thank you. I will try to run, and use the other suggestions as well, I'm more inclinded to trying to understand basics than using imports, but it is all helping out

Answer (score 1):

Aside of using `defaultdict`, you can try to catch that exception (known as [It’s Easier To Ask Forgiveness Than To Get Permission](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12265451/ask-forgiveness-not-permission-explain)):

```py
def graph_dict(filename):
    dictx = {}
    with open(filename) as x:
            for i in x:
                c, c1, c2 = i.split()
                try:
                    dictx[c] += [(c2,c1)]
                except KeyError:
                    dictx[c] = [(c2, c1)]
    return dictx
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `.setdefault()`

```
def graph_dict(filename):
    dictx = {}
    with open(filename) as x:
        for i in x:
            c, c1, c2 = i.split()
            dictx.setdefault(c,[]).append((c2,c1))
        return dictx
print(graph_dict(r'c:\test\dat.txt'))
```

```
{'s1': [('s2', '10'), ('s3', '14')], 's2': [('s3', '12')], 's3': [('s1', '25')]}
```

Comment: This is good except that it creates a list for each `setdefault`, even if its not needed. Its a reasonably fast operation so likely won't affect the execution too much.

Answer (score 0):

```
from collections import defaultdict 

def graph_dict(filename):
    dictx = defaultdict(list)
    with open(filename) as x:
        for i in x:
            c, c1, c2 = i.split()
            dictx[c] += [(c2,c1)]
        return dictx

print(graph_dict('data'))
```

Comment: This is really nice, I tried it and I like the way it is written