# What is the pythonic way to check that both values are None or not None together

Tags: python, python-3.x

I a have a function with 2 variables set be default to `None`

```
def foo(x, y=None, z=None):
    ...
```

I want to make sure that if they are passed they both need to be not None.

I did the following:

```
if y is not None:
    assert z is not None
```

But I wonder if there is a more elegant way of doing this check.

If only 1 of them is None I want to assert while if both of them are it's ok.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do something like this

```
if (y is None) == (z is None):
   # both are None or both are not None
else:
  # one of them is None
```

Answer (score 2):

You should avoids using an `assert` statement as it is intended for testing and debugging purposes, rather than controlling program flow.

```
def foo(x, y=None, z=None):
    if (y is None) == (z is None):
        # rest of your code here
    else:
        raise ValueError("Both y and z must be either None or not None")
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use the XOR operator to make sure exactly both values are what you expect, but I'm not sure that's any more readable or elegant.

`assert not ((y is not None) ^ (z is not None))`

Answer (score 0):

With `any` - `all` functions:

```
def foo(x, y=None, z=None):
    y_z = (y, z)
    if any(y_z): assert all(y_z)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the pythonic way would be to [ask for forgiveness rather than permission](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12270384/7648657), aka not testing both values and dealing with the exceptions.

If this is not possible in your case then I think it depends on the logic of your function.

Is it important to fail immediatly if `y` and `z` are inconsistent ?
Do you actually just want to be sure `z` is not none if `y` isn't (what your code currently do) ?
Is it important to inform the caller that the arguments are inconsistent ? Or you just want to avoid an error ? (ex: `z` has a value but not `y`, may be that does not provoke an error but it looks like a wrong call. If your function is "public" it seems a good practice to fail in that case. If not, you might not need to deal with it)