# WinError 5 Access is denied:

Tags: python

I was working on a project where a recursive program would look through my computer to find a specific file. When it tries to open the recycle bin, the following error is produced:
The function that produces this error is this:

```
def containsFile(path, filename):
    print(path, os.access(path, os.R_OK))
    for thing in os.listdir(path):
        if(thing == filename):
            return os.path.join(path, filename)
        return False
```

I tried to test permissions for the file by printing `os.access(path, os.R_OK)` to the console, but it says that I have access to the recycle bin in the console. Is there a way to check for files/folders I don't have access to? Thanks in advance.

Comment: "check for files/folders I don't have access to"?  What kind of "check" might be done without any access?

Comment: Reading a file and enumerating a directory are different permissions, if I recall correctly. And in this case, it's better to ask forgiveness than permission; you might just catch the `PermissionError` or whatever it's throwing and handle it; *that's* your check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap the call to `containsFile` in a try/except block to catch the Permission Error.  The paradigm in Python is to try to do the possibly bad thing and catch the exception aka ["It's Easier to Ask Forgiveness than Permission" aka EAFP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12265451/ask-forgiveness-not-permission-explain)

```
def main():
    ...
    try:
        result = containsFile(path, filename)
    except PermissionError as e:
        print(f"Unable to search {path} : {e}")
        # Maybe add something here to skip ahead to the next path?
    else:
        # Handle the result True/False
    ....
```