# What would be a good way to pass through my methods one and check the result from each?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am new to Python programming but trying to make a password checker to that checks for certain things in a single string input. I want to restart the while loop if any method returns else.

```
def length():
    if len(password) > 8:
        print("Password is long enough. ")
    else:
        print("Password too short, please try a new password. ")


def numbers():
    if len([num for num in password if num.isdigit()]) >= 2:
        print("Password has two digits. ")
    else:
        print("Password needs two digits, please try a new password. ")



def lower():
    if any(map(str.islower, password)):
        print("Password has lower case. ")
    else:
        print("Password needs an lowercase letter, please try a new password.")



def upper():
    if any(map(str.isupper, password)):
        print("Password has upper case. ")
    else:
        print("Password needs an uppercase letter, please try a new password.")



while True:
    password = str(input("What is your password? \n"))
    length()
    numbers()
    lower()
    upper()
```

I don't know what I could do to efficient go through these methods and check if I get the result I want.

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7129285/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-return-statement-how-is-it-different-from-printing

Comment: By the way, you don't need spaces at the end of your strings or before `\n`. Also: "an lowercase" -> "a lowercase" (see my code).

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this:

```py
from typing import List


def length(pwd: str) -> bool:
    return len(pwd) > 8


def numbers(pwd: str) -> bool:
    return len([num for num in pwd if num.isdigit()]) >= 2


def lower(pwd: str) -> bool:
    return any(map(str.islower, pwd))


def upper(pwd: str) -> bool:
    return any(map(str.isupper, pwd))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    functions_to_check: List = [length, numbers, lower, upper]
    is_password_satisfactory: bool = False
    password: str = ""
    while not is_password_satisfactory:
        password = str(input("What is your password? \n"))
        is_password_satisfactory = all(map(lambda f: f(password), functions_to_check))
    print(f"{password} is satisfactory")
```

Just a quick recap on how `any` and `all` work: they both take as argument a list of booleans, and return `True` if any (or all the) elements inside the list are `True`.
Expanding on that idea, we first list what are the functions we must use to verify our passwords (`functions_to_check`).
Then we will loop until the password is valid.
We check if the password is valid by building a list of booleans representing if the password passed each check (`map(lambda f: f(password), functions_to_check)`: we apply each verification function to the password and store the result inside a list) and then we check whether all the elements of this list are `True` or not (we pass it as argument to the `all` function).
We then store the result of the `all` function into the variable we use to continue looping, and if the password is valid, we break.

Comment: Should it be `while not password_satisfactory:` ?

Comment: I think the name was just confusing, I changed it to `is_password_satisfactory`. This value is `False` if any of the checks is False, so putting `while not is_password_satisfactory` would be to say that every password except those satisfying the conditions are acceptable.

Comment: But `while cond` means we will keep asking for a password **until** `cond` is true. We stop asking when `cond` is False. So `cond` should express the condition that the password is **not** acceptable.

Comment: As it stands, the `while` loop will never run, because `is_password_satisfactory` is initialised to False. Have you run this code to test it?

Comment: Ah, you're absolutely right! Absolutely sorry for my earlier answer! I tested it and it ran well, until I tried refactoring while writing my answer...

Comment: Haha, can't claim I've never done that myself :)

Answer (score 0):

You can return a boolean value from your function that acts as a flag whether the while loop should continue or not.

If the password has not any uppercase letter the function return True so the loop keeps calling upper().

I encourage you to try to find how to implement it for all functions.

```py
def upper():
    if any(map(str.isupper, password)):
        print("Password has upper case. ")
        return False #exit
    else:
        print("Password needs an uppercase letter, please try a new password.")
        return True # keeps going

flag = True
while flag:
    password = str(input("What is your password? \n"))
    flag = upper()
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Add arguments to your functions.
2. Have your functions return `bool` values.
3. Use `break` to break out of the `while`-loop if all conditions are met.

```
def length(password):
    if len(password) > 8:
        print("Password is long enough.")
        return True
    else:
        print("Password too short, please try a new password.")
        return False

def numbers(password):
    if len([num for num in password if num.isdigit()]) >= 2:
        print("Password has two digits.")
        return True
    else:
        print("Password needs two digits, please try a new password.")
        return False

def lower(password):
    if any(map(str.islower, password)):
        print("Password has lower case.")
        return True
    else:
        print("Password needs a lowercase letter, please try a new password.")
        return False

def upper(password):
    if any(map(str.isupper, password)):
        print("Password has upper case.")
        return True
    else:
        print("Password needs an uppercase letter, please try a new password.")
        return False

while True:
    pw = str(input("What is your password?\n"))
    if (length(pw) and numbers(pw) and lower(pw) and upper(pw)):
        break
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to returning Booleans is using exceptions:

```py
class InvalidPasswordException(Exception):
    pass


def validate_length(password: str):
    if len(password) < 9:
        raise InvalidPasswordException("Password too short, please try a new password.")


def validate_numbers(password: str):
    if len([num for num in password if num.isdigit()]) < 2:
        raise InvalidPasswordException("Password needs two digits, please try a new password.")


def validate_lower(password: str):
    if not any(map(str.islower, password)):
        raise InvalidPasswordException("Password needs an lowercase letter, please try a new password.")


def validate_upper(password: str):
    if not any(map(str.isupper, password)):
        raise InvalidPasswordException("Password needs an uppercase letter, please try a new password.")


def get_password() -> str:
    while True:
        try:
            password = str(input("What is your password? \n"))
            validate_length(password)
            validate_numbers(password)
            validate_lower(password)
            validate_upper(password)
            return password
        except InvalidPasswordException as error:
            print(error)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    get_password()
```

Also, you probably want to break out of your `while True` loop. For this you can use either `break` or `return` (if it is inside a function).

Using exceptions is neither better nor worse than the other approach. It is more of a different style (see also ["ask for forgiveness not permission"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12265451/ask-forgiveness-not-permission-explain)).