# how to handle KeyError: 'choices' with chatGPT?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, openai-api, keyerror, chatgpt-api

i have an interface for chatgpt which usually works, but randomly seems to come up with a KeyError that i currently cannot resolve or avoid.
it uses the solara library to create a web page from the Python code in a jupyter notebook.

```
try:
    global gMemory #memory of chat stored as string
    gptResponse.value = "==GENERATING-RESPONSE==" #output

    url = "https://api.openai.com/v1/completions"
    headers = {"Content-Type": "application/json", "Authorization": "Bearer [REDACTED]",}
    data = {"model": "text-davinci-003", "prompt": ((gMemory + "\nUSER REQUEST: " + text).strip()), "max_tokens": 3000, "temperature": 1.0,}
    response = requests.post(url, headers=headers, json=data)
    out = str(response.json()['choices'][0]['text'].strip())

    gMemory += "USER REQUEST: " + text + out + "\n" #text is the users request, out is the openai response
    gptResponse.value = "" #clears output
    gptResponse.value = gptResponse.value + out
        
except KeyError:
    time.sleep(10)
    gptResponse.value = "==ERROR-//-ENTER-A-NEW-REQUEST-;-OR-REFRESH=="
    time.sleep(10)
    submitButton.value = False #allows requests to be submitted again
```

the above code sends the request to openai, along with the conversation history (combined into one string). It then updates the history with the new message and updates the output value for the gui

i have put this all into a try except, which is able to catch the error. however, the error still persists when attempting to send any new requests, irrelevant of how long i wait to send a request or if the request is different. it only works after refreshing the page, which loses all history and restarts the program.

Comment: you assume the response will include 'choices' but clearly it doesn't

Comment: @KennyOstrom how would i solve this?

Comment: the problem i seem to be experiencing is that some of the time 'choices' is there; other times it isn't. i tried adding some code to see if it finds 'choices' and it still worked the exact same. sometimes fine, sometimes crashing

Comment: Do you want me to write up an answer where you add checks like if succeeded(response.status_code) and 'choices' in response.json(): ... or should I talk about how your retry strategy sounds a little like send the exact same request and hope for a different response?

Comment: Or you can do what you're already doing. Just assume the response meets your expectations, and have an exception handler for all other cases. But if you don't know what caused the exception, it's going to be tough to adapt to it for the next request.

Comment: @KennyOstrom im a little confused as to why you seem to have gotten so confrontational, unless im just reading too far into what you said. i'm asking for help because the program makes a request (i believe in the correct way), but the response from the api is not in the format expected. since it is a well known api, i was hoping someone else may have run into this or someone may have an idea of what could be going on. unless i am mistaken, the issue seems to be in the response i'm getting from the api, or an issue with jupyter or solara.

Comment: By adding a block of code to display response.json() without any formatting, it shows the error that is present. the error being that the prompt and response can only add up to 4097 tokens; but they total to too high. so ill have to reduce the size of response allowed. less than ideal, but it is a solution.

Comment: no ... exceptions are good in python. That's a legit strategy in python, which takes a lot of performance tradeoffs to deliver good exception handling. I can see why that might have sounded sarcastic if you're used to exceptions in other languages, sorry about that.

Comment: see also https://stackoverflow.com/a/12270384/1766544

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By adding a block of code to display response.json() without any formatting, it shows the error that is present. the error being that the prompt and response can only add up to 4097 tokens; but the total is too high. so ill have to reduce the size of response allowed. less than ideal, but it is a solution.

tldr: `"max_tokens": 3000` needs changing to a lower value, as the token count becomes too high as the conversation continues and requires more space.

`max tokens` is actually just the maximum for the response. but you still need to consider the size of the request.