# Cross-version portability in Python

Tags: python, portability

This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2654149/850781) offers two approaches to computing bit length of an `int`:

1. All versions: `len(bin(x))-2`
2. 2.7+: `x.bit_length()`

I need my code to work with 2.6+, so I cannot use the second solution.

Is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1093322/850781) the best I can do?

```
import sys
if sys.hexversion < 0x02070000
    def bitlen(x): return len(bin(x))-2
else:
    def bitlen(x): return x.bit_length()
```

The alternative is

```
try: 
    (1).bit_length()
    def bitlen(x): return x.bit_length()
except AttributeError:
    def bitlen(x): return len(bin(x))-2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would probably write it as:

```
def bitlen(x): 
    """The bit length of the integer x."""
    try:
        return x.bit_length()
    except AttributeError:  # I guess!
        return len(bit(x)) - 2
```

This removes the need for an explicit version check. If you want to factor the check out of the function, perhaps:

```
if hasattr(1, 'bit_length'):
    bitlen = lambda x: x.bit_length()
else:
    bitlen = lambda x: len(bit(x)) - 2
```

Comment: the problem with this approach is that the check is done on each invocation

Comment: @sds *is* that a problem?

Comment: this is definitely an aesthetic problem for me; it could also be a performance issue.

Comment: @sds updated with an alternative; testing with `timeit` suggests that the `bit_length` version is faster, so I'd go with that where possible.

Comment: thanks, any reason to use `lambda` instead of `def` (IOW, is there a problem with non-top-level `def`?)

Comment: @sds just an aesthetic objection to the one-line `def` form; I would either use a `lambda` or spread the function over two lines.

Answer (score 0):

This would work on 2.6 and below as well as above.

```
def bitlen(int_type):
    length = 0
    while (int_type):
        int_type >>= 1
        length += 1
    return(length)
# and then
bitlen(0b10000) # --> 5
```

Check out, https://wiki.python.org/moin/BitManipulation, for further reading

Comment: Although portable, this is pretty slow; it takes four times as long as the `len` version and seven times as long as using `bit_length`.

Comment: Yes, though I thought to add it in just for plain portablitity :)