# python: bit trick to find number of bits required to represent a number

Tags: python, bit-manipulation, bit

In python I want to calculate the number of bits required to represent an unsigned number. For eg:

```
2 --> 2 bits
3 --> 2 bits
10 --> 4 bits
```

I am simply calculating it as follows `len( bin( n ) ) - 2`

Is there any other better way to calculate this ? purely using bit manipulation so that I can use it on other languages as well ?

Comment: Use `int.bit_length(integer)` python2.7, `a=10 a.bit_length()` python3

Comment: Your method looks ok, you could also use `ceil(log(n, 2))` but that may be more expensive.

Comment: Important to consider if you are using signed or unsigned numbers too...

Comment: @zetysz I want to use just bit manipulation so that I can port it to other language.

Comment: @ilent2 just unsigned numbers

Comment: @user881300: Ultimately, working with bits is a very low-level thing to do, and high-level languages are going to have very different ways to support it (including no support at all in some cases). In most cases, you'll have to find out how the target language does it anyway. If you *truly* want portability, you should definitely *not* ask for a bit-twiddling trick.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2654149/count-bits-of-a-integer-in-python

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way is to use the [`.bit_length()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#int.bit_length) method of `int` type:

```
>>> for n in (2, 10):
...     print(n.bit_length())
... 
2
4
```

If you want to do the bit twiddling yourself, you could use the following function:

```
def bit_length(n):
    bits = 0
    while n:
        bits += 1
        n >>= 1
    return bits
```

Comment: is there a way I can avoid python specific method and find it using just bit manipulation or something so that I can port it to other language like C ?

Answer (score 2):

If you really want a bit to do it, then

```
count=0
while(n!=0):
 n=n>>1
 count+=1
```

Comment: Shouldn't that be n>>1?