# Is there a built-In function in python to count the number of 1's in a number?

Tags: python

Please suggest an efficient algorithm if no such library function exists.

Comment: Mathematically there are 'the number' of 1's in any 'the number'.

Comment: I assume you talk about the number of 1s in the representation of the number in a specific number system. Decimal perhaps? Or binary? Both are common, and others are possible.

Comment: The correct term would be 'digits'. "Count the `1` digits in a number" would be a clearer way of expressing your question.

Comment: If you mean counting the ones in the binary representation of a number, take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9829578/566644) question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

something like `str(number).count("1")` ?

Comment: Of course, that's assuming OP is talking about the decimal system (the hamming weight, which is about the binary system, is quite common).

Comment: Indeed, but I am guessing this is what the O.P. wants, since there is no information to assert it -- it can be wrong should the O.P. ever clarify the question.

Comment: Or we could just refuse to answer bad questions instead of guessing.

Answer (score 3):

Something like:

```
for baseconv in (int, oct, hex, bin):
    as_text = str(baseconv(123456789))
    print as_text, as_text.count('1')
```

Comment: Let's hope he never wants to count zeroes :)

Answer (score 2):

For the number of '1's in the binary representation, an 8 bit lookup table is quite efficient. eg. for 32 bit numbers

```
>>> tab=[0, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 3, 1, 2, 2, 3, 2, 3, 3, 4, 1, 2, 2, 3, 2, 3, 3, 4, 2, 3, 3, 4, 3, 4, 4, 5, 1, 2, 2, 3, 2, 3, 3, 4, 2, 3, 3, 4, 3, 4, 4, 5, 2, 3, 3, 4, 3, 4, 4, 5, 3, 4, 4, 5, 4, 5, 5, 6, 1, 2, 2, 3, 2, 3, 3, 4, 2, 3, 3, 4, 3, 4, 4, 5, 2, 3, 3, 4, 3, 4, 4, 5, 3, 4, 4, 5, 4, 5, 5, 6, 2, 3, 3, 4, 3, 4, 4, 5, 3, 4, 4, 5, 4, 5, 5, 6, 3, 4, 4, 5, 4, 5, 5, 6, 4, 5, 5, 6, 5, 6, 6, 7, 1, 2, 2, 3, 2, 3, 3, 4, 2, 3, 3, 4, 3, 4, 4, 5, 2, 3, 3, 4, 3, 4, 4, 5, 3, 4, 4, 5, 4, 5, 5, 6, 2, 3, 3, 4, 3, 4, 4, 5, 3, 4, 4, 5, 4, 5, 5, 6, 3, 4, 4, 5, 4, 5, 5, 6, 4, 5, 5, 6, 5, 6, 6, 7, 2, 3, 3, 4, 3, 4, 4, 5, 3, 4, 4, 5, 4, 5, 5, 6, 3, 4, 4, 5, 4, 5, 5, 6, 4, 5, 5, 6, 5, 6, 6, 7, 3, 4, 4, 5, 4, 5, 5, 6, 4, 5, 5, 6, 5, 6, 6, 7, 4, 5, 5, 6, 5, 6, 6, 7, 5, 6, 6, 7, 6, 7, 7, 8]
>>> N=123456789
>>> tab[N>>24]+tab[N>>16&255]+tab[N>>8&255]+tab[N&255]
16
```