# Is this an efficient way to generate the Thue-Morse sequence in Python?

Tags: python, generator

Is using a generator as in the code below, an efficient way to generate the [Thue-Morse sequence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thue%E2%80%93Morse_sequence) in Python?

```
# generate the Thue-Morse sequence
def genThueMorse():
    # initialize
    tms = '0'
    curr = 0
    while True:
        # generate next sequence
        if curr == len(tms):
            tmp = ''
            for i in range(len(tms)):
                if tms[i] is '0':
                    tmp += '1'
                else:
                    tmp += '0'
            tms += tmp
        yield tms[curr]
        curr +=1
```

Here is code to test it:

```
tms = koch.genThueMorse()
while True:
   print(next(tms))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is concise, is it "efficient"?

```
import itertools

def genThueMorse():
    for n in itertools.count():
        yield (1 if bin(n).count('1')%2 else 0)
```

Comment: This is exactly the right idea; a closed-form representation avoids the need to store the entire sequence-so-far within the generator (which makes the generator itself look silly). As for how to actually count the bits, see also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9829578/fast-way-of-counting-bits-in-python

Comment: Nice. No extra memory used. Then the problem moves into fast ways of counting bits. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9829578/fast-way-of-counting-bits-in-python

Comment: Re: `yield (1 if bin(n).count('1')%2 else 0)` -- since `bin(n).count('1') % 2` is 1 when you return 1 and 0 when you return 0, you should be able to write the code like this: `yield bin(n).count('1') % 2`. Maybe your way is more explicit about returning 1 or 0.

Comment: @hughdbrown: good point. I don't remember what I was thinking back then, so I can't claim that I purposely wrote it that way to be more explicit, although it is. There is certainly an efficiency gain in removing the `if/else` ..

Answer (score 1):

I think a generator will be fairly efficient. I would go for something like this:

```
from itertools import count, izip

def genThueMorse():
    tms = [0]
    invert = [1, 0]
    for tm, curr in izip(tms, count()):
        yield str(tm)
        if curr == len(tms) - 1:
            tms += [invert[c] for c in tms]
```

Comment: Why not change `counter = count(); while True: curr = counter.next()` to `for curr in count():`?

Comment: @icktoofay: good idea. I initially thought that such a loop would stop on 0.

Answer (score 1):

Helping to complement the other answers: If you only want to calculate the nth digit in the sequence use:

`lambda n:  bin(n).count("1") % 2`

or if prefer a function:

```
def calculate_nth(n):
  return bin(n).count("1") % 2
```

**Example:**

```
f = lambda n:  bin(n).count("1") % 2
f(0) # This will return 0
f(1) # This will return 1
f(2) # This will return 1
...
f(10) # This will return 0
```

This can be verified with the sequence: **0** **1** **1** 0 1 0 0 1 1 0 **0** 1 0 1 1 0