# Fast algorithm to find sets of boolean vectors that are almost mutually exclusive

Tags: python, algorithm, numpy, combinatorics

I am looking for a fast algorithm to solve the following problem in Python:

I have a set of boolean vectors of length `M`

`B[1],B[2]...B[N]` where `length(B[i]) == M` and `B[i] in [0,1]` for all `i`

I want to find all subsets of size `K <= N` that are *almost* mutually exclusive. That is, I want to enumerate the indices of vectors `subset_idx` such that:

- `len(subset_idx) <= K` (subsets of at most `K` vectors)
- `sum(B[subset_idx), axis = 0) <= 1` at least `M - T` times (mutually exclusive)
- `sum(B[subset_idx), axis = 0) > 1` at most `T` times (not mutually exclusive)

Here:

- `T` is a ``fudge factor" for the mutual exclusivity requirement. If `T = 0`, then the vectors in `subset_idx` must be mutually exclusive.
- By mutually exclusive, I mean that that `B[i,k] && B[j,k] = 0` for all vectors `i, j` in the `subset_idx` for almost all cases (i.e. `M - T` cases).

As an example, I included a sloppy implementation that uses `numpy` and `itertools` below. I think that both the algorithm and the implementation can be improved. I'm looking for a better algorithm, but any implementation-related pointers would be appreciated.

```
import numpy as np
import itertools

K = 3       #max size
T = 0       #fudge factor for mutual exclusivity requirement

B = np.array(
    [[1, 1, 0, 1, 0],
     [0, 0, 1, 1, 0],
     [1, 1, 0, 0, 1],
     [1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
     [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
)

N, M = B.shape

# if you want to generate vectors randomly, use:
#
#  np.random.seed(seed=1)
# N = 10      #number of vectors
# M = 20     #length of each vectors
# B = np.random.choice([0, 1], size = (N, M))


mutually_exclusive_subsets = []

#identify subsets that are almost mutually exclusive via exhaustive search
for subset_size in range(2, K):
    for subset_idx in itertools.combinations(range(N), subset_size):
        n_exclusive = np.sum(np.sum(B[subset_idx,], axis=0) <= 1)
        if n_exclusive >= (M - T):
            mutually_exclusive_subsets.append(subset_idx)

print mutually_exclusive_subsets
# >>> [(0, 4), (1, 2), (1, 4), (2, 4), (3, 4)]


#test that each subset identified is *almost* mutually exclusive
for exclusive_idx in mutually_exclusive_subsets:
    assert(np.sum(np.sum(B[exclusive_idx,], axis = 0) > 1) <= T)
```

Comment: The Hamming distance determines the number of different elements in (binary) strings and has implementations in numpy/scipy.
Possible relevance: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32730202