# Binary matrix multiplication

Tags: python, numpy

I got a matrix *A*, with the following bytes as rows:

```
11111110  (0xfe)
11111000  (0xf8)
10000100  (0x84)
10010010  (0x92)
```

My program reads a byte from stdin with the function `sys.stdin.read(1)`. Suppose I receive the byte *x* `10101010 (0xaa)`. Is there a way using numpy to perform the multiplication:

```
>>> A.dot(x)
0x06 (00000110)
```

As `A` is a 4x8 matrix, compossed by 4 bytes as rows, and `x` is an 8 bit array, I was expecting to receive the (nibble `0110`) byte `0000 0110` as a result of the multiplication `A * x`, treating bits as elements of the matrix.

If the elements of the matrix were treated as binary bytes, the result would be:

```
>>> A = np.array([[1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0],[1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0],[1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0],[1,0,0,1,0,0,1,0]])
>>> x = np.array([1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0])
>>> A.dot(x)%2
array([0, 1, 1, 0])
```

Comment: How exactly do you expect to get 0x06? Could you walk me through the manual steps (in your question) please?

Comment: Please add to your question. There is no way someone reading your question could have figured that out.

Comment: Please work through the actual steps in your question.

Comment: If A is 4x8, are the individual bits matrix elements? Are the nibbles matrix elements (in which case A is 4x2)? How are you actually doing this?

Comment: @MadPhysicist. Yes I want to treat the bits as elements of the matrix. I wonder if this can be done with `numpy`.

Comment: It sure can. Please make your question explicit instead of ambiguous. Can you show how you get the final answer, because I am getting 84 if I operate on just the bits.

Comment: The smallest representable size in numpy is one byte `uint8` I believe

Comment: @romeric. That is irrelevant.

Comment: since A is shape (4,8), and x is (8,), then `A.dot(x)` should be shape (4,), not a scalar.  You haven't yet explained clearly what you meant by "treating bits as elements of the matrix".

Comment: Specifically, I understand how you do the row-wise multiplication of A and x (I think), but I do not understand how you add the results of that together to get 0x06 (I get 4 or 84) using two different methods. Unless you are willing to explain that, I think your question is unanswerable. If you do explain it, I can have an answer for you in 2 minutes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## 1. Not using `dot`

You do not need to fully expand your matrix to do bitwise "multiplication" on it. You want to treat `A` as a 4x8 matrix of bits and `x` as an 8-element vector of bits. A row multiplication yields 1 for the bits that are on in both `A` and `x` and 0 if either bit is 0. This is equivalent to applying bitwise and (`&`):

```
>>> [hex(n) for n in (A & x)]
['0xaa', '0xa8', '0x80', '0x82']
```

```
10101010
10101000
10000000
10000000
```

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9829578/2988730) is a post on counting the bits in a byte. `bin(n).count("1")` is probably the easiest one to use, so

```
>>> [bin(n).count("1") % 2 for n in (A & x)]
[0, 1, 1, 0]
```

If you want just a number, you can do something like

```
>>> int(''.join(str(bin(n).count("1") % 2) for n in (A & x)), 2)
6
```

## 2. Using `dot`

To use `dot`, you can easily expand `A` and `x` into their numpy equivalents:

```
>>> list(list(int(n) for n in list(bin(r)[2:])) for r in A)
[['1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '0'],
 ['1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '0', '0', '0'],
 ['1', '0', '0', '0', '0', '1', '0', '0'],
 ['1', '0', '0', '1', '0', '0', '1', '0']]
>>> list(int(n) for n in bin(x)[2:])
[1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0]
```

You can apply `dot` to the result:

```
>>> np.dot(list(list(int(n) for n in list(bin(r)[2:])) for r in A),
           list(int(n) for n in bin(x)[2:])) % 2
array([0, 1, 1, 0])
```

Comment: Thank you for the answers, not using `dot` seems better solution.

Comment: It's definitely shorter and requires less converting to and from strings.