# Python Simplifying if's conditions that contains ORs and ANDs

Tags: python, if-statement, simplify

I'm making in-console Battleship game in Python and I have a code that checks if the ship can fit into the list. It does not look very appealing and I'd like to simplify it into a more appealing version.

```py
if (direction is "N" and row - size < 0) or \
  (direction is "E" and column + size > 10) or \
  (direction is "S" and row + size > 10) or \
  (direction is "W" and column - size < 0):
    print("It does not fit")
```

I was thinking of using the dictionary, but couldn't think of a way to use variables and maths operator (-+ <>) inside

Comment: Do not use `is` for equality comparisons. Use `==` (`is` checks for identity, whether two objects are the same. The fact that it works here is an implementation detail, and may break.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if any([direction is "N" and row - size < 0, direction is "E" and column + size > 10, direction is "S" and row + size > 10, direction is "W" and column - size < 0]):
    print("It does not fit")
```

Sure there is a lot of improvement with your code to but this is a start

Other improvements

```
if any([direction == "N" and size > row, direction == "E" and column + size > 10, direction == "S" and row + size > 10, direction == "W" and size > column]):
```

A better way, more clear;

```
dir_classifier = {'N': size > row, 
'E': (column + size) > 10,
 'W': size > column,
 'S': (row + size > 10)}


if dir_classifier[direction]:
     print("It does not fit")
```

Answer (score -1):

**Direct approach**

```
conds = (
    (direction is "N" and row - size < 0),
    (direction is "E" and column + size > 10),
    (direction is "S" and row + size > 10),
    (direction is "W" and column - size < 0),
)

if any(conds):
    print("It does not fit")
```

**With refactoring**

If possible, remove "negation" from condition. Then extract condition to a function `is_fit(direction, row, column, size)`. So it will look like this:

```
if is_fit(direction, row, column, size):
    print('It fits!!!')
else:
    print('It does not fit')
```

This way it looks neat and easy to read.

Further, you can create a proper `Ship` class with properties like `size`, `direction`, `column`, `row`. Then it will look even better:

```
if is_fit(ship):
    print('...')
```

Also, `is_fit` can be a method of `Ship` class:

```
if ship.is_fit():
    print('...')
```

Comment: Why should I remove negation? This 'if' is in function that validates input-related stuff, and therefore I'm checking if arguments do not pass the conditions.

Comment: To make it easier to read. Only for that. With the negation it's harder to create a proper name for the function. Even adding `not` before the function name in the condition will be easier to read (in case you don't need `else` part).

Answer (score -1):

Well, its not the most readable way, but i think it a cool think to notice

```py
def is_valid(direction):
    n = ord(direction)
    bits = count_bits(n)
    result = (bits == 4) * row) + ((bits != 4) * col) + ((((n&7)==6) * -1) * size
    if (0 > result > 10):
        print('invalid')

def count_bits(n):
  n = (n & 0x5555555555555555) + ((n & 0xAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA) >> 1)
  n = (n & 0x3333333333333333) + ((n & 0xCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC) >> 2)
  n = (n & 0x0F0F0F0F0F0F0F0F) + ((n & 0xF0F0F0F0F0F0F0F0) >> 4)
  n = (n & 0x00FF00FF00FF00FF) + ((n & 0xFF00FF00FF00FF00) >> 8)
  n = (n & 0x0000FFFF0000FFFF) + ((n & 0xFFFF0000FFFF0000) >> 16)
  n = (n & 0x00000000FFFFFFFF) + ((n & 0xFFFFFFFF00000000) >> 32) # This last & isn't strictly necessary.
  return n
```

Counting bit functino from : [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9830282/7434857)

## Explanation

count_bits - counts the set bits of a number

`S` and `N` require to use the `row` element, which they both have 4 set bits in there ascii value, so it help us to determ the using of the value row or colum, it there are 4 set bits, we use the `row`, and if not, we use the `col`.

then we need to know if we want to substract the size, or adding it up, then we use `(((n&7)==6)` which tells as if the 3 lsb is equals to 6, which will be true for `N` and `W`