# Python - RNN LSTM model low accuracy

Tags: keras, deep-learning, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

I have tried to build LSTM model with this sample of dataset

> (patient number, time in mill/sec., normalization of X Y and Z,
>   kurtosis, skewness, pitch, roll and yaw, label) respectively.
>
> 1,15,-0.248010047716,0.00378335508419,-0.0152548459993,-86.3738760481,0.872322164158,-3.51314800063,0
>
> 1,31,-0.248010047716,0.00378335508419,-0.0152548459993,-86.3738760481,0.872322164158,-3.51314800063,0
>
> 1,46,-0.267422664673,0.0051143782875,-0.0191247001961,-85.7662354031,1.0928406847,-4.08015176908,0
>
> 1,62,-0.267422664673,0.0051143782875,-0.0191247001961,-85.7662354031,1.0928406847,-4.08015176908,0

and this what i have done with the code

```python
np.random.seed(7)

train = np.loadtxt("featwithsignalsTRAIN.txt", delimiter=",")
test = np.loadtxt("featwithsignalsTEST.txt", delimiter=",")

x_train = train[:,[2,3,4,5,6,7]]
x_test = test[:,[2,3,4,5,6,7]]
y_train = train[:,8]
y_test = test[:,8]

x_train = x_train.reshape((-1,1,6))

model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(64,activation='relu',input_shape=(1, 6)))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='softmax'))

model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy',
              optimizer='adam',
              metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit(x_train, y_train, batch_size = 128, epochs = 10, verbose = 2)
```

there is no error but the accuracy is very low and the loss is very high

> Epoch 1/20
>    - 63s - loss: 15.0343 - acc: 0.0570 Epoch 2/20
>    - 60s - loss: 15.0343 - acc: 0.0570 Epoch 3/20
>    - 60s - loss: 15.0343 - acc: 0.0570 Epoch 4/20
>    - 60s - loss: 15.0343 - acc: 0.0570

Comment: The error gives it, check `x_train.shape` and see if the new shape matches. This is not an error related to Keras; possible [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26295491/valueerror-total-size-of-new-array-must-be-unchanged)

Comment: the error could be in the dataset itself ?

Comment: you probably mean x_train.reshape((-1, 1, 6)), not (1, 1, 6)

Comment: Try to remove `activation='relu'`. LSTM was designed to work with `tanh` that is the default.

Comment: i tried to remove it but it still gives me the same accuracy and loss

Comment: how much data do you have? And what is the accuracy after 20 epochs?

Comment: training samples is 1,415,684 and testing samples is 502,203.. and after 20 epochs the accuracy is 0.0570

Answer (score 1):

the wrong here is the use of the softmax activation function,, because it is used for categorical problems.. but this is a binary problem so the best activation function is the sigmoid