# Python - Best way to find similar images in a directory

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-imaging-library

Here is the effect I am trying to achieve - Imagine a user submits an image, then a python script to cycle through each JPEG/PNG for a similar image in the current working directory.

Close to how Google image search works (when you submit your image and it returns similar ones). Should I use PIL or OpenCV?

Preferably using Python3.4 by the way, but Python 2.7 is fine.

Wilson

Comment: This might help - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13379909/compare-similarity-of-images-using-opencv-with-python

Comment: Also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/75891/algorithm-for-finding-similar-images

Comment: http://scikit-image.org/

Comment: http://www.pyimagesearch.com/2014/12/01/complete-guide-building-image-search-engine-python-opencv/

Answer (score 1):

I mean, why not use both? It's trivial to convert PIL images into OpenCV images and vice-versa, and both have niche functions that can make your life easier. Pair them up with sklearn and numpy, and you're cooking with gas.

Answer (score 0):

I created the [undouble](https://erdogant.github.io/undouble) library in Python which seems a match for your issue.

It uses Hash functions to detect (near-)identical images in for example a directory. It works using a multi-step process of pre-processing the images (grayscaling, normalizing, and scaling), computing the image hash, and the grouping of images based on a threshold value.