# Is there a built-in python function to count bit flip in a binary string?

Tags: python, string

Is there a built-in python function to count bit flip in a binary string? The question I am trying to solve is given a binary string of arbitrary length, how can I return the number of bit flips of the string. For example, the bit flip number of `'01101'` is 3, and `'1110011'` is 2, etc.

The way I can come up with to solve this problem is to use a for loop and a counter. However, that seems too lengthy. Is there a way I can do that faster? Or is there a built-in function in python that allows me to do that directly? Thanks for the help!

Comment: No, no there isn't. Although you could use `itertools.groupby` to simplify your code, and it should be at least slightly faster

Comment: What do you mean by "a binary string"? Do you have *text* that consists of `1` and `0` *characters*, like what you get by pressing the 1 and 0 keys on a keyboard? Or are you looking at raw data at the byte level and observing the pattern of set and clear bits? Or something else?

Comment: @Karl Knechtel Thanks for the comment, I am looking for a string-like input :) Just edited the OP

Answer (score 4):

There is a **very fast way** to do that without any explicit loops and **only using Python builtins**: you can convert the string to a *binary number*, then detect all the bit flips using a **XOR-based integer tricks** and then convert the integer *back to a string* to *count* the number of bit flips. Here is the code:

```py
# Convert the binary string `s` to an integer: "01101" -> 0b01101
n = int(s, 2)

# Build a binary mask to skip the most significant bit of n: 0b01101 -> 0b01111
mask = (1 << (len(s)-1)) - 1

# Check if the ith bit of n is different from the (i+1)th bit of n using a bit-wise XOR:
# 0b01101 & 0b01111 -> 0b1101  (discard the first bit)
# 0b01101 >> 1      -> 0b0110
# 0b1101 ^ 0b0110   -> 0b1011
bitFlips = (n & mask) ^ (n >> 1)

# Convert the integer back to a string and count the bit flips: 0b1011 -> "0b1011" -> 3
flipCount = bin(bitFlips).count('1')
```

This trick is **much faster than other methods** since integer operations are very optimized compare to a loop-based interpreted codes or the ones working on iterables. Here are performance results for a string of size 1000 on my machine:

```
ljdyer's solution:    96 us     x1.0
Karl's solution:      39 us     x2.5
This solution:         4 us    x24.0
```

If you are working with short bounded strings, then there are even [faster ways to count the number of bits set in an integer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/407587/python-set-bits-count-popcount).

Answer (score 3):

Don't know about a built in function, but here's a one-liner:

```
bit_flip_count = len([x for x in range(1, len(x0)) if x0[x] != x0[x-1]])
```

Answer (score 2):

Given a sequence of values, you can find the number of times that the value changes by *grouping contiguous* values and then counting the groups. There will be one more group than the number of changes (since the elements before the first change are also in a group). (Of course, for an empty sequence, this gives you a result of -1; you may want to handle this case separately.)

Grouping in Python is built-in, via the standard library `itertools.groupby`. This tool only considers contiguous groups, which is often a drawback (if you want to make a histogram, for example, you have to sort the data first) but in our case is exactly what we want. The overall interface of this tool [is a bit complex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/773/how-do-i-use-itertools-groupby), but in our case we can use it simply:

```
from itertools import groupby

def changes_in(sequence):
    return len(list(groupby(sequence))) - 1
```